# Texmaker not compiling references

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, biber

I am using Texmaker and Miktex, and having issues to compile the references. In my latex file:

```
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
style=numeric,%
sorting=none,%
]{biblatex}
```

I am using quick build: pdfLaTeX+View PDF.

When I compile it gets printed linke this:
[image]

When I compile the same file in ShareLatex it works perfect, so must be some configuration errors.

Do anyone know what the errors are?
[image]

Running Biber manually returns:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.2
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.9, expected version 2.8
INFO - Found 46 citekeys in bib section 0 
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'citations.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'citations.bib'
WARN - Duplicate entry key: '7027553' in file 'citations.bib', skipping ...
WARN - Entry ok2006 does not parse correctly
WARN - ISBN '159829556X, 9781598295566' in entry 'Hoelzle' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'oracle' (citations.bib): Invalid format 'n.d' of date field 'date' - ignoring
ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\BILALA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AI_7lm2bHk\citations.bib_7640.utf8, line 585, syntax error: at end of input, expected one of: name (entry type, key, field, or macro name) or end of entry ("}" or ")")
INFO - WARNINGS: 5
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: The line for Bib(la)tex should mention `biber` not `bibtex` since you backend is biber.

Comment: @Bernard I have tried both, changed to biber now. Still not now working.

Comment: Please see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations: TeXmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/35864). You will want to use "PdfLaTeX + Bib(La)TeX + PdfLaTeX (x2) + View PDF" for quick build or run Biber manually (probably via F11? or the menu) so that Biber is actually run. "pdfLaTeX+View PDF" alone probably doesn't run the bibliography programme.

Comment: I tried to run biber manually, and that returned (see updated post)

Comment: The `.blg` shows quite some problems. Firstly, your versions of `biblatex` and Biber don't match. Update your distribution before you proceed (see [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864); please note that currently some MikTeX mirrors might be down and might not respond, if you can't make an update don't panic, wait till tomorrow and try again). Also check the other warnings: You seem to have  at least two `7027553`s, in `Hoelzle` you should only give one ISBN in the `isbn` field, ...

Comment: .. if you have no date in `oracle`, so drop the `date` field ("n.d." can be added automatically), the entry `ok2006` does not parse correctly check for missing commas and braces. Then something is not quite right around line 585, check for missing braces there as well. Finally note that you have to run LaTeX after you have run Biber to get to see the bibliography. Normally one runs (in this order) (pdf)LaTeX, Biber, (pdf)LaTeX, (pdf)LaTeX. See also [Question mark instead of citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/) and [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/).

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Comment: Any news here? I'm quite tempted to close your question as a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) since that was your original problem and the other problem cannot really be solved without seeing the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Default Bibliography Tool is set to `txs:///biber`
If so, run Biber alone from the menu (Tools > Commands > Biber), and then compile it again, should work.

Have you tried to delete the .aux file? Sometimes if it's generated with a bug or something it's faster to remove and re-compile.