# biber stops during compilation, results in empty bbl file

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber

I want to use `lualatex` and `biber` with the help of MiKTeX on Windows 8.1. Following is a MWE (`test.bib`) :

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

this is a test file \cite{test1}.

\end{document}
```

and the bibliography file (`test.bib`):

```latex
@BOOK{test1,
  AUTHOR = {Terrence Test},
  TITLE = {Testing is Trying and Troubling},
  YEAR = {1987},
}
```

I can compile `test.tex` just fine:

```
lualatex test.tex
```

which gives me (among others) a `test.bcf` file that I feed to `biber`:

```
biber test.bcf
```

This command prints among the correct looking `INFO` output a whole lot of:

```
Use of uninitialized value in lc at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-726965686d\cache-2ee463ceb881db975cd39064dffff28a85695787\inc\lib/Biber.pm line 424.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-726965686d\cache-2ee463ceb881db975cd39064dffff28a85695787\inc\lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 201.
```

I have deleted this folder several times but it always comes back.

The output of `test.blg` is:

```
[0] Config.pm:340> INFO - This is Biber 2.4
[1] Config.pm:343> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[48] biber-MSWIN64:287> INFO - === 
[62] Biber.pm:347> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[137] Utils.pm:147> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.7, expected version 3.0
[570] Biber.pm:741> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[595] Biber.pm:3150> INFO - Processing section 0
[665] Biber.pm:3307> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
[671] bibtex.pm:1124> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[673] bibtex.pm:985> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
```

and the `test.bbl` file is plain empty. The installed versions are:

```
C:\>lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 5238)

C:\>biber --version
biber version: 2.4
```

and `biblatex` is on version 3.3 from 2016-03-09 according to MiKTeX Package Manager.

Does anyone of you nice people know what I can do so I can finally enjoy using `biber` on this Windows machine (please not that I do not have admin rights)? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: An which biblatex version do you have according to your log-file? biber at least says that biblatex is too old: §found biblatex control file version 2.7, expected version 3.0"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try deleting all auxiliary files? Biber tells us that the `.bcf` file it got was created by a `biblatex` version considerably older than v. 3.3. Maybe you have two versions of `biblatex` on your PC. Do an update in both User and Admin mode (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)). You can add `\listfiles` to the very to of your file and check the used version of the packages in the `.log` file.

Comment: That warning means you are using incompatible versions of biber and biblatex. Your biblatex is older than your biber. See the compatibility matrix in the PDF documentation for either biblatex or biber.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your prompt help. There were indeed leftovers of an old installation of MiKTeX in another directory which led `biber` to a wrong path. So especially the answer of @moewe put me in the right direction.

Comment: See also [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a conflict caused by the remnants of another TeX distribution interfering with the path settings. The problem has been resolved by the OP (see comments above).