# Problem with the bibliography (biblatex) on TeX STudio

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm discovering biblatex and i have a few problem or misunderstanding.
I'm actually working with TeX Studio and when i'm trying to run the bibliography, I have the following message:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: rapport.aux
>   I found no \citation commands---while reading file rapport.aux
>   I found no \bibdata command---while reading file rapport.aux
>   I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file rapport.aux
>   (There were 3 error messages)

The thing is I trying a lot of different solutions shown in different topics and no one had the correct solution to my problem...

Here is my code:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}



 \begin{filecontents*}{rapport.bib}
    @online{cim-wiki,
        author = {Wikipedia},
        title = {Common Information Model (electricity)},
        date = {11.04.2016},
        url =    {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(electricity)},
    }
    \end{filecontents*}


   \bibliography{rapport}
   \chapter{Bibliographie}

   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
```

---

new version of the code:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}


       \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
       \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
    \usepackage{siunitx}
       \usepackage{csquotes}
       \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
       \usepackage{float}
       \usepackage{circuitikz}
       \usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pstricks-add}
       \usepackage{geometry}
       \usepackage{titlesec}
       \usepackage{xcolor}
       \usepackage{sectsty}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}


   \bibliography{rapport}
\begin{document}
 \chapter{Bibliographie}
 \nocite{cim-wiki}
 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

with the following bib file:

```
 @online{cim-wiki,
    ALTauthor = {Wikipedia},
    ALTeditor = {editor},
    title = {Common Information Model (electricity)},
    date = {4 February 2016, at 04:26.},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(electricity)},
OPTurldate = {11/04/2016},
 }
```

Comment: You need to run biber not bibtex.

Comment: You are probably running BibTeX when you should be running Biber, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Check also [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) and [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: Thanks it has solve this first problem but the blibliography still does not show... I will had my code in question in my post above

Comment: It is unclear to me if you are using the filecontents environment in your real document (you should not) or if it is just for the example. http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: I actually tried both and neither of the solutions worked..
What happens is that he tell me that there is an option clash for package biblatex

Comment: Have you actually cited anything? Nothing is cited in this incomplete minimal example (there is no `\begin{document}` for example). Only things directly cited goes into the bibliography (unless you for example ask it to take everything from the `.bib` file.

Comment: Plus I'm not use if `\bibliography{...}` is the proper syntax for `biblatex`, that is a bibtex thing

Comment: no I did not cite anything yet, but how do I ask it to take everything from the bibfile?

Comment: `\nocite{*}` works with normal bibtex.

Comment: I actually modified \bibliography by changing it to \addbibresource and the first problem still remains...: "Option clash for package biblatex. \usepackage"

Comment: You can use `\bibliography{file}`, but `\addbibresource{file.bib}` is preferred. Note that both of those commands must be called in the preamble and not in the document. As others have already commented, in your document you don't cite anything and consequently won't see any output-

Comment: Don;t load the package twice with different options, see my answer below

Comment: Indeed I missed this one^^ my bad

Comment: I do not understand I corrected all of it following your instruction it does not show any errors but still it does not show any bibliography

Comment: Can you update your post with the code you are trying to use now. Can you also show any errors and warnings you get in the `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: done this is the only thing in the log file :      Biber reported the following issues(biblatex) with 'cim-wiki':(biblatex) - Datamodel: Entry 'cim-wiki' (rapport.bib): Invalid format '4 February 2016, at 04:26.' of date field 'date' - ignoring.

Comment: Yes, the date in the `date` field must be given in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You also have no author for the entry. Except for the very bloated preamble, this looks fine and the warnings you report aren't that bad either. What is the output?

Comment: @moewe there is nothing in output, I mean for the bibliography, and there are no errors

Comment: I can hardly believe that. If you have a `\nocite` and `\printbibliography` and you get no further error or warnings, you should also get an output. But since the problem seems solved anyway, it's probably not something we need to lose sleep over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more minimal AND working example, using `biber` not `bibtex`

Note that `biber` complains about the format of the date, so you'll need to look that up in the `biblatex` manual.

You probably mean `urldate` not `date`, and then the syntax is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so

```
urldate = {2016-04-11},
```

in this case.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
 \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{rapport.bib}
  @online{cim-wiki,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    title = {Common Information Model (electricity)},
    urldate = {2016-04-11},
    url =    {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(electricity)},
  }
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{rapport}

\begin{document}

   \chapter{Bibliographie}

\cite{cim-wiki}

   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
```

Comment: @SvenGlöyer If the answer solves your problem, you might want to accept the answer.