# PDFLatex throws errors, undefined control sequence, use of \sortlist doesn't match it's definition, etc

Tags: biblatex, errors, pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I recently asked a question about using biblatex, but that didn't seem to be a problem.

I now used some code which should work fine, but I'm still getting errors. Here is the code I used:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
  AUTHOR    = {John Doe},
  TITLE     = {The Book without Title},
  PUBLISHER = {Dummy Publisher},
  YEAR      = {2100},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text \cite{DUMMY:1} Text
\section{Test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm using MiKTeX and the Editor called TeXmaker. What I'm trying to use is fast compile, with the setting to then compile as PdfLaTeX + Biblatex + PdfLaTeX(x2).  The first time PdfLaTeX runs fine, Biblatex as well, but then I get lots of erros, here are all of them:

```
! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition.
l.21   \sortlist{
                 nty}{nty}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.21   \sortlist{nty}
                     {nty}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Undefined control sequence.
\entry ...ata@\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 
                                                  @\abx@field@entrykey }\csu...
l.22     \entry{DUMMY:1}{book}{}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...equal \expandafter {\blx@slist@type 
                                                  }{entry} {\listcsxadd {blx...
l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...equal \expandafter {\blx@slist@type 
                                                  }{list} {\blx@bbl@labelfie...
l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.37     \endentry

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 

l.38   \endsortlist

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)
! Extra \endgroup.
\blx@bblinput ...nit \blx@bblfile@biber \endgroup 

l.20 \begin{document}

Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.

Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 20.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 20.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DUMMY:1' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 23.

[1

{C:/Users/schuessl/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(test2.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test2
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test2.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test2.run.xml'.

 )
```

Does anybody know why these errors are thrown and what the problem is?

**Edit**: Here's the filelist I'm getting (as suggested in comments):

```
*File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2016/01/08 3.9n The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 ngerman.ldf    2013/12/13 v2.7 German support for babel (new orthography)
csquotes.sty    2016/01/31 v5.1g context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2016/01/31 v5.1g csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)

kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
 numeric.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.def    
standard.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
  german.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ngerman.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   test2.bbl
 ***********
```

And here the content of the `.blg`-file:

```
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - This is Biber 2.3
[0] Config.pm:330> INFO - Logfile is 'test2.blg'
[37] biber-MSWIN:284> INFO - === 
[62] Biber.pm:346> INFO - Reading 'test2.bcf'
[156] Utils.pm:147> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9
[157] Biber.pm:689> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[163] Biber.pm:3066> INFO - Processing section 0
[187] Biber.pm:3206> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test2.bib' for section 0
[195] bibtex.pm:1062> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[200] bibtex.pm:923> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test2.bib'
[228] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[229] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[229] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'de-DE'
[229] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[247] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[248] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[248] Biber.pm:2943> INFO - Sorting list 'nty' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nty' and locale 'de-DE'
[249] Biber.pm:2947> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[252] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'test2.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[253] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to test2.bbl
[253] Biber.pm:107> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Comment: Delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`). If the problems persist, make sure both `biblatex` and BIber are up to date and their versions match. See [troubleshooting for Biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) for general advice on that matter.

Comment: @moewe I did now delete all three files, but getting the same errros, both, biber and biblatex, are up to date.....

Comment: Please show the `.log` and `.blg` files (add `\lisfiles` to the top of the `.tex` file and report the list of packages and version numbers you get near the end of the `.log`). Maybe you have an older `biblatex` version on your machine that is picked up instead of the up-to-date one. If you use MikTeX do an update in both Admin and User mode (there are two different updaters).

Comment: @moewe see my edited question, I'm currently also updating everything again, but I don't think that might change anything...

Comment: `WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9` Update `biber`.

Comment: Your Biber version is outdated, you have 2.3, but for `biblatex` 3.3 you need 2.4. If you have installed Biber via MikTeX's Package Manager an update should solve the problem. If you have installed Biber manually, please delete the manual installation and re-install it via the Package manager. (You may or may not have to do an update after that.)

Comment: Gosh, this really solved the problem, thank you. Even if it's very interesting, that Biber is in the wrong version, because I installed everything (even MikTex) on Friday (this week), so I wonder that versions didn't match but however it works now. Thank you :) You might put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that a fresh MikTeX installation does not automatically give you the newest package versions. That is why the install help page advocates an update right after the installation procedure. Version issues are normally closed as 'off topic' here (they are not really, but it is the best closing reason we have left), so I suggest we go down that way here as well.

Comment: For information, `biblatex`/`biber` incompatible version messages will be more explicit and fatal in the next release.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update (Biber was on v. 2.3, but 2.4 was needed).