# Including the bibliography doesn't work

Tags: biblatex, citing, texworks

Good afternoon,

I am a new to LaTeX and currently I am writing on my thesis, but I got problems on including my bibliography which is implemented as a .bib file. Probably I should add that there are no errors.
I use: TeXworks and Jabref (for creating the .bib file)

Overview of what doesn't work:

- Citations in text with correct numerations (i.e. [1])
- Attachment of a bibliography section at the end of the document with corresponding entry in the content list

---

For example: sources.bib

`@Book{Schroeder2000,
  title     = {Elektrische Antriebe - Grundlagen},
  publisher = {Springer Verlag},
  year      = {2000},
  author    = {D. Schroeder},
}`

In my .tex file I want to include this .bib file. So I got something like that (There was a template given to me which contains the following lines, I tried to adjust them for my purposes but it didn't work):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

% packages
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, backref, sorting=none]{biblatex} % use backend=biber if available
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} % \definecolor{heatred}[RGB}{170,0,0}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx} % \SI{15e3}{\kg}, \SI{0.2}{\m\per\s}, \si{\kWh}
\usepackage{mdwlist} % compact lists: \begin{enumerate*}, \begin{itemize*}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm} % bold italic symbols in math mode
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}

% table of contents
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

% content
%Include your introduction, etc.
\input{tex/01-intro}
\input{tex/02-main}
\input{tex/03-end}

% Bibliography
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But when I cite in one of my tex documents (i.e. main.tex) it doesn't work.

---

This is how I cited in my .tex file:

`And Mr. P stated that XYZ has happened \cite{Schroeder2000}`

This is the output I get from the previous line:

And Mr. P stated that XYZ has happened [**Schroeder2000**]

Instead of:

And Mr. P stated that XYZ has happened [1]

---

Additionaly the last part:

```
% Bibliography
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
```

doesn't work, too. There is no bibliography section in my table of contents and there is no bibliography attached at the end of the document.

I am very sorry if the writing-style doesn't apply to the forum standards. It is my very first time here at this forum. Of course I searched for answered questions but I couldn't find any answers to my problem.
I would like to thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How are you compiling? Did you run some sequence like `pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex`?

Comment: Mhmm. It says "pdfLatex +MakeIndex + BibTex" at the very top. Somehow there is no option like "biber" available?!

/// I guess that this is the main problem. That there is no Biber typeset 'installed'. So my goal should be to get pdflatex + MakeIndex + Biber, right?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767/36296

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to implement it as described. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: Note that you don't need all the `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline` stuff, you only need `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`.

Comment: Any news here? Did setting up your editor as in the question linked help? If not can you update your question with details of what you did and what exact error/warnings/undesired output you get now?

Comment: I managed to find a way around. Since I do not really need the features of Biber, I simply changed the backend to BibTex
'\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=BibTex, backref, sorting=none]{biblatex}'
This works for me. Does any problem pop up your mind with my solution? Is there something which won't work with the changed backend? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Well, BibTeX is considered a "legacy backend", the full feature set can only be expected to work with Biber. (There was even a discussion to drop the BIbTeX backend entirely.) So you it would be better to try and get Biber to work. Have a look at [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).

Comment: So what do we do about this question? I would have said it is a duplicate of the "configure my editor for Biber" question linked to before, but since you opted for BibTeX, I'm not sure. Maybe you could try and get Biber off the ground.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try and as soon as I make progress I will update.

Comment: @moewe Question mark/bold citation key instead of citation number?

Comment: @Johannes_B I thought about the Biber-editor question, but then the OP said he would update us on the progress, so I decided to wait until he confirms that things work with Biber.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Biber won't work with me. BibTex does fine (up to now). I do not understand why Biber refuses to cooperate ... I thought I had done everything like advised, but still no success.

Comment: Mhhh, still I think this question is going nowhere. So would you mind terribly if we closed it as a duplicate of the "run Biber" question - which is really what ought to be done here? If you can't run Biber you might want to ask a question at a more support-orientet forum like http://golatex.de/ (I take it you speak German).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advise, let's close this question and I will ask at the considered forum again.