# Everything updated but still "! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition."

Tags: biblatex, biber

I upgraded to a new CPU and installed windows all over. I then downloaded MikTeX 2.9 from the official website and Texmaker.

Biber I downloaded from sourceforge which downloads the file `biber-cygwin64.tar.gz`. After unzipping I copy the folder to my system drive and add it in Texmaker and set the path: [image: texmaker].

Compiling files without bibliography files works just fine (I conclude MiKTeX and Texmaker work properly).

Compiling documents using references results in an error:

```
! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition.
```

which has been documented before in this forum (stack exchange does not let me post any additional links but you find searching for "Error “Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. \sortlist{”")

I fail to solve the problem by updating the individual components as suggested in the other stackexchange post. MiKTeX packages cannot be updates as there are not updates available:

[image]

and the biber version cannot be outdated since I just downloaded it a couple of minutes ago. The same document works just fine on my laptop, where I use Texmaker as well.

Anyone any idea on how to fix this?? I would really appreciate any help!

---

EDIT 1:
After updating the MiKTeX packages on my laptop I get the same error message. So it seems to be related to the `biblatex` package in MiKTeX.

---

EDIT 2:
Using a mini-example as suggested, I can move one step further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib} 
\begin{document}
 b 
\parencite{Archarya.2016}
\cite{Archarya.2016}
\printbibliography \end{document}
```

Quick build works, but the second step (running BibTex) results in a new error:

```
Process started
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: newtest.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file newtest.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file newtest.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file newtest.aux (There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

Most likely because my path under Bib(la)tex in Texmaker is not correct (in that I reference to the sourceforge file and not what it really should be)

Comment: First of all, welcome. Second: Don't install stuff from sourceforge. `biber` is shipped with `MikTeX. No need to install separately.

Comment: Have you checked that it is not related to your code? Which is now outdated? biblatex got an non-backwar-compatible update a while back.

Comment: hey Johannes, thanks for your reply. I wasn't aware that biber comes with MiKTeX, I thought only Biblatex did. in any case, what would you have me choose under "bib(lat)tex" option in TexMaker?

Comment: in the preable I use: 

\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits=true,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,, url=true,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,uniquename=false, uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    bibliography={biblio},
    andothers={et\ al\adddot},
    urlseen = {Abruf am},
}

\bibliography{biblio}

Comment: Why on't you just ask on a [german site](http://golatex.de/)? Instead, you are placing stuff in comments which shoul be added to the question. Try out [the small examples](http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html) to know what your real problem is.

Comment: i migrated the code from a german document to an english one, that's why I posted here. I am trying an mini example:

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
b
\parencite{Archarya.2016}
\cite{Archarya.2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`

Compiling works, but executing BIbtex does - of course - not because it is not define in the texmaker settings (where I still reference to the old biber thing I downloaded from sourceforge. I tried to reinstall texmaker to get back the original setting, but it still references to the wrong.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: hey,
it does work with the mini example, but not on my big file. I will try to figure out why that is the case.

Comment: In your second edit you give a log file of BibTeX. BibTeX is not biber. My last link aboe as well as the *wichtige Hinweise* (linked) tell you where you have to put what. http://texwelt.de/wissen/upfiles/TMconf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never install Biber or `biblatex` manually from SourceForge or any other source, unless you know exactly what you are doing and you have a good reason to do so.

If you are running MikTeX, there is hardly ever a reason to do a manual install.
So you should

1. Remove the manual installation of Biber you got from SourceForge.
2. Check that `biblatex` and Biber are installed in MikTeX.

   - If not, install the corresponding packages.
   - If you have the biber package installed, but you overwrote it with your manual install you may have to uninstall and then reinstall it.
3. Make an update. (With both the User version of MikTeX update and the Admin version. To be sure, run each wizard twice.)

Then you need to ensure that you actually run Biber.

4. [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

If you still have problems with your document, delete the auxiliary files and try to recompile from a clean directory. Refer also to [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).