# PDFLatex doesn't find Bib File

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, jabref

Sorry for the newbee question...
But that did somehow work a few days ago, but not now anymore... But I really don't know what I've changed...

Biblatex Version: 3.7
Biber Version 2.7

I have a folder Structure like:

```
threads.tex
include
|--> literatur-datenbank.bib
|--> multiple other files
```

A Sample from my datenbank-literatur.bib looks like this:

```
@Book{rauber,
  Title                    = {Multicore: Parallele Programmierung},
  Author                   = {Rauber, T.},
  Year                     = {2008}
}
```

my Threads.tex looks like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside,parskip=half,headings=normal]{scrreprt}
\input{includes/_praeambel.tex}

\bibliography{includes/literatur-datenbank}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
```

Log File loks like this:

```
.
.
.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 4.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'rauber' on page 2 undefined on input line 5.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have you run biber? We can only assume what you actually use. You would help us help you by providing a MWE with bibliography.

Comment: You need to run Biber on your file. If you have done that Biber will produce a `.blg` file, that is a simple text file. Check its contents and report them here. If Biber can't find the file it will complain, if something else went wrong you will see that there as well.

Comment: See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864)

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run Biber? Do things work now? What does the `.blg` say?

Comment: Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot! I had to first run pdflatex to get the bcf file, then biber to create the bibstuff and then pdflatex again.