# biblatex not sorting the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

I'm writing my dissertation in LaTeX  and I cannot make the bibliography appears in citation order.

I'm using `biblatex` and I've used the `sorting=none` but is not working. At first it was working fine but after trying to change the citation style to harvard style, it stopped working. I deleted all the changes I made but is not working anymore. I don't know it's a problem with mendeley (I use it to manage my references), my code or something else.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles} %For join each section
\usepackage{graphicx} %For images and tables
\usepackage{subfig} %For sub images
\usepackage{float} %For the tables and images?
\usepackage{amssymb} %Math symbols
\usepackage{setspace} %Spacing
\usepackage{sectsty} %Italic subsection
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} %Table colours.
\usepackage{multirow} %Multirows
\usepackage{hhline} %For lines in the columns with colours
\usepackage{longtable} %Long tables
\usepackage{framed} %For Boxes
\usepackage{float} %Floats environment for caption in boxes.
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% Captions outse Float For use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage[width=16.5cm, left=2.5cm, height=25.7cm]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{5pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{5pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\sectionfont{\large\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\paragraphfont{\normalfont\bfseries\itshape}
\newfloat{Box}{tpbh}{Box} %Creates float "environment" Box

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex}%For the References

\addbibresource{Project.bib} %The references

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \clearpage
    %\@mainmatterfalse
    \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \clearpage
    % \@mainmattertrue
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
    \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
    \else
    \clearpage
    \fi
    % \@mainmatterfalse
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        ...
    \end{titlepage}

    \newgeometry{width=16.5cm, left=2.5cm, height=25.7cm}

    \frontmatter
    \onehalfspacing
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listof{Box}{List of Boxes}
    \clearpage
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

    \mainmatter

    \subfile{Introduction.tex}
    \subfile{background.tex}
    \subfile{Ch1.tex}
    \subfile{Ch2.tex}
    \subfile{Ch3.tex}
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

    \backmatter
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: It 'is not working' is not a helpful description of your problem at all. We need to know what you expect to see and what you see instead. If there were problems, TeX normally informs you about them in the `.log` file, Biber will write complaints to the `.blg` (on Windows the file extension is associated with the 'Performance Monitor', but Biber's `.blg`s are simple text files that you can open with your favourite editor). Did you try to delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and compile again? Did you run Biber?

Comment: See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).

Comment: Note that your code example is not an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (click the link to see what an MWE is): You are loading a lot of packages that are unrelated to your problem. But more importantly, we don't have any of your `\include`'d files neither do we know how your `Project.bib` looks like, so there is no way for us to run your example. Please try to reduce it to reproduce your problem with as little code (and noise from `\include` and unnecessary packages) as possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it by rewriting the `bib` file (see comment under the answer). The `bib` file is not shown in the question ...