# Trying to use Chicago but footnote only shows key, not the citation

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

I've been trying to make a citation in TeXstudio using Chicago, and can't get the footnote to give me anything other than the key.

I have MiKTex installed, which I was hoping would fix the problem, but no luck.

text.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}  
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


Testing\footcite{Saussure1995}

Testing the second citation\footcite{Labov1972}


\end{document}
```

And this is the output for my footnotes:

1. Saussure1995
2. Labov1972

Any idea why it's not working? Is there something in either the Commands or Build configurations that I should have changed once I installed MiKTex?

Comment: Make sure you run `pdflatex`then`biber` then `pdflatex`. Check for any errors in logs in case your version of `biber` is out of date.

Comment: Works for me. Have a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864). Please show us the `.blg` file you get after the Biber run (it is a short plain text file you can open with your favourite text editor, even if Windows classifies it as a 'performance monitor' file.)

Comment: Any news here? Did configuring your editor and running Biber help? If not, can you show us the `.blg` file?