# Biber and Biblatex incompatible versions

Tags: biblatex, biber

I recently had to reinstall Windows 10.  Upon doing so, my Miktex and Texmaker were deleted and needed to be reinstalled as well.  I have been learning LaTeX via Texmaker since July of this year.

After I had reinstalled Texmaker and Miktex, I went to run my dissertation document.  I use BibLatex and Biber for the references.  When I run the document, the following error message appears below:

INFO - This is Biber 2.7 INFO - Logfile is 'Dissertation Master File.blg' INFO - Reading 'Dissertation Master File.bcf' ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3. This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.8a) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

My questions are, has anyone ran into this problem before and how do I fix it?  Please feel free to inform me of anything you need from my end as this is my first question asked and I am a novice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Comment: `miktex-biber` was updated to version `2.8` a week  ago.

Comment: If you're using version 3.8a (2017/11/05) of biblatex, you must use version 2.8 of biber. Your installed version, 2.7, isn't sufficiently up to date.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.  How do I go about installing version 2.8?  I've updated everything through Miktex (admin and user) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: So I updated Biber to 2.8.  But now there's a new error message.  When I compile the document to include the bibliography, when I run Biber, this message appears:


INFO - This is Biber 2.8 INFO - Logfile is 'Dissertation Master File.blg' INFO - Reading 'Dissertation Master File.bcf' INFO - Found 144 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Dissertation.bib' for section 0 ERROR - Data file 'Dissertation.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'ascii': ascii "\xE2" does not map to Unicode at (file location).

I've been using Zotero to export.

Comment: Please try to isolate the entry in the `.bib` file that causes the problem. There are some known issues with Biber 2.8 about character mapping, and 2.9 should be released soon with a fix. But I'm not sure if your problem is the same, we would need to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I don't know if it's something with Zotero but if I export the bib file into a biblatex format it shows this error.  If I export it as a Bibtex file, it works fine.  Any ideas what happened?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this could be a problem with wrongly encoded files. The new version of Biber (2.8) is slightly more picky now when it comes to file encodings. But we would need to see an example that reproduces the problem to help.

Comment: The encoding issue is explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402714/35864. Since the issue in the body of the question is about a version mismatch I vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a clearly stated version incompatibility that was solved by updating the packages involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber)