# Understanding Abbreviation using Jabref and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, jabref

```
@Article{gk25en,
  author    = {Gk},
  title     = {hljhjdlasjdhkjfahkf},
  year      = {1925},
  journal   = {International Journal of Communication Systems},
}
@Article{jt,
  author    = {Gk},
  title     = {hljhjdlasjdhkjfahkf},
  year      = {1925},
  journal   = {Journal of Lightwave Technology},
}
```

When I used **ctrl+alt+A** in Jabref (Tools->Abbriviate journal names)

```
@Article{gk25en,
  author    = {Gk},
  title     = {hljhjdlasjdhkjfahkf},
  year      = {1925},
  journal   = {Int. J. Commun. Syst.},
}
@Article{jt,
  author    = {Gk},
  title     = {hljhjdlasjdhkjfahkf},
  year      = {1925},
  journal   = IEEE_J_JLT,
}
```

Which reflects in reference section (texstudio,biblatex):

gk25en: shown perfectly as: *Int. J. Commun. Syst.*

jt: Everything OK, except NO journal name shows in the reference section. I was expecting to show this as: *J. Lightw. Technol.*

Comment: The journal name in `jt` will only show if you have an entry of the form `@string{IEEE_J_JLT = {Int. J. Commun. Syst.}}` in your `.bib` file or in a separate file you also load with `\addbibresource`.

Comment: See also https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2485. I guess you only need `\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}`. OR go to *options -> preferences -> advanced* and uncheck "Use IEEE LaTeX abbreviations".

Comment: I added `\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}` where it is written `@STRING{IEEE_J_JLT        = "J. Lightw. Technol."}` not as `@string{IEEE_J_JLT = {J. Lightw. Technol.}}`. However, in compile message it shows `warning: undefined macro "IEEE_J_JLT"`. Is that the problem of `"" and {}`

Comment: I see. Biber chokes on `IEEEabrv.bib` because it contains the non-ASCII char `á` (apparently as ANSI) in the comments ... That's a tricky one.

Comment: But changing `á` to `a` not solving the problem.

Comment: Just checked. It absolutely solves the problem for me.

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/216 is not actually a problem. In what order do you load the `.bib` files? The one defining the `@string`s should come first. I.e. put `\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}` before `\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}`.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I used your method described in 2nd comment.

Comment: Of course I put the wrong link I meant https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/218. Do you want me to type up a short answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is pretty simple. Instead of giving the value of a field with `journal = {J. Lightw. Technol.}`

```
journal   = IEEE_J_JLT,
```

sets `journal` up to use the value of a `@string` variable instead. That variable will be defined in a `.bib` file as

```
@STRING{IEEE_J_JLT = "J. Lightw. Technol."}
```

so you can use it. By changing that variable in a single location you can then influence multiple entries at once.

There are several issues here.

If you use the IEEE abbreviations in JabRef (see https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/2485), you will need to load either `IEEEabrv.bib` for abbreviated journal names or `IEEEfull.bib` for full journal names.
So you need

```
\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}
```

Note that `IEEEabrv.bib` needs to be loaded first since it provides the `@string` entries later used by your `.bib` file. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/218.

The last point is more problematic. `IEEEarbv.bib` contains one non-ASCII char (namely an `á` in `Nicolás Barabino`). If your document is set up so that it assumes UTF-8 or ASCII-encoded `.bib` files, Biber can not read that file properly and chokes (see [BibLaTeX not working with Biber 2.8 - error reading .bib file in ascii format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402714/35864) for background on that). If your document is `latin1`-encoded anyway or all your `.bib` files are in `latin1` you may get away with this by telling TeX or Biber to use `latin1`. Otherwise you will need to modify `IEEEarbv.bib`. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it, rename it to `IEEEarbv-ascii.bib` and change `Nicolás Barabino` to `Nicol\'{a}s Barabino`. Then note in the header that you changed the file to pure ASCII. While the file is distributed under the LPPL, it explicitly states

> ```
> Retain all contribution notices and credits.
> ** Modified files should be clearly indicated as such, including  **
> ** renaming them and changing author support contact information. **
> ```

So you should probably avoid making that file public. (Though I think they should be fine with that change to the credits. But IANAL.)