# TeXShop not generating bbl files on Mac

Tags: biblatex

I'm using texshop on a Mac, and for some reason it's not generating bbl files upon first compilation. My source code starts out like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amstext,amscd,euscript,mathrsfs,amsfonts,amsbsy,amsxtra,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[all]{xy} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\numberwithin{figure}{section} 
\allowdisplaybreaks
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable and add two of your bib entrys to your question. Show us how you call them for your bibliography ...

Comment: If that really is your code, no compiler will generate anything but errors. In any case, why is this tagged `biblatex`? Why is it tagged `hyperref`? You load lots of things, but don't seem to be using either of those packages. You are loading lots of pointless things: most of the `ams` packages are unneeded with `ams` classes and several of them are unneeded even with standard classes, given the others. I'm think some of them are just overriding each other in terms of font configuration. I'd recommend switching TeXShop to use UTF-8 by default and amending the input encoding for new documents.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you have shown us so far does not show us how you generate your bibliography (it does not load any bibliography packages - in particular not `biblatex`). but of course that is crucial information for a question about the `.bbl`. Please provide a full, yet minimal [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows us what you are trying to do.

Comment: The standard problems are: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 (the last two are only relevant if you are indeed using `biblatex` as the tagging suggests, if not you should retag your question and read only the first link).

Comment: Any news here? Your question is lacking important detail. As it is now it cannot be answered.

Comment: Any news here? The code snippet you have shown us makes no reference to the bibliography, so it is really hard to tell what is going on. Note also that `.bbl` files are not generated upon the first compilation with LaTeX, they are generated by BibTeX/Biber and can only be written if an `.aux`/`.bcf` file is found (those are produced by a successful LaTeX run).