# Bibliography is only printing keyword in ArsClassica

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, classicthesis

I am using the ArsClasica thesis style, and this is the main code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
               headinclude,,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
               numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,%
               tablecaptionabove]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian,american]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{varioref}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,subfig,beramono,eulermath,pdfspacing,listings]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\input{arsclassica-settings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%******************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%******************************************************************
\input{FrontBackMatter/Titlepage}
\input{FrontBackMatter/Titleback}
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Abstract+Sommario}
\input{FrontBackMatter/Acknowledgements}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Contents}
\cleardoublepage
%******************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%******************************************************************
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/Fundamentals}
\input{Chapters/Code}
% *****************************************************************
% Backmatter
%******************************************************************
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Bibliography}
\clearpage
\input{FrontBackMatter/Index}
\end{document}
```

in the arsclassica-settings:

```
% ********************************************************************
% arsclassica-settings
% ********************************************************************





% ********************************************************************
% hyperref
% ******************************************************************** 
\newcommand{\mail}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\texttt{#1}}}


% ********************************************************************
% makeidx, multicol
% ********************************************************************
\let\orgtheindex\theindex
\let\orgendtheindex\endtheindex
\def\theindex{%
    \def\twocolumn{\begin{multicols}{2}}%
    \def\onecolumn{}%
    \clearpage
    \orgtheindex
}
\def\endtheindex{%
    \end{multicols}%
    \orgendtheindex
}

\makeindex


% ********************************************************************
% listings
% ********************************************************************

\definecolor{lightergray}{gray}{0.99}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Emerald}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\rmfamily,
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightergray}
} 

\lstset{    morekeywords=%
        {RequirePackage,newboolean,DeclareOption,setboolean,%
        ProcessOptions,PackageError,ifthenelse,boolean,%
        chapterNumber,sodef,textls,allcapsspacing,%
        MakeTextLowercase,orgtheindex,endtheindex,%
        @ifpackageloaded,undefined,sfdefault,%
        DeclareRobustCommand,spacedallcaps,%
        microtypesetup,MakeTextUppercase,lowsmallcapsspacing,%
        lowsmallcapsspacing,spacedlowsmallcaps,
        spacedlowsmallcaps,lehead,headmark,color,%
        headfont,partname,thepart,titleformat,part,
        titlerule,chapter,thechapter,thesection,%
        subsection,thesubsection,thesubsubsection,%
        paragraph,theparagraph,descriptionlabel,titlespacing,%
        graffito,lineskiplimit,finalhyphendemerits,%
        colorbox,captionsetup,labelitemi,%
        myincludegraphics,hypersetup,setlength,%
        definecolor,lsstyle,textssc,subsubsection,%
        graffito@setup,includegraphics,ifdefined,%
        myTitle,textcopyright,myName,lstset,lstnewenvironment,%
        setkeys,lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile,contentsname,%
        toc@heading,@ppljLaTeX,z@,check@mathfonts,%
        sf@size,ptctitle,mtctitle,stctitle,lst@intname,%
        @empty,math@fontsfalse,@ppljscTeX,@iwonaTeX,%
        @iwonascLaTeX,@ctTeX,tw@,ct@sc,@ctTeX,f@family,%
        f@shape,ct@sc,ctLaTeX,ctLaTeXe,@twoe,@sctwoe,%
        texorpdfstring,m@th,ctTeX,@mkboth,ProvidesPackage,%
        theindex,PackageInfo,PackageWarningNoLine,%
        mtifont,mtcindent,@iwonaLaTeX,@ppljTeX,@iwonascTeX,%
        rohead,orgendtheindex,@ppljscLaTeX,%
        @ifclassloaded,toc@headingbkORrp,backreftwosep,%
        backrefalt,backreflastsep,areaset,pnumfont,%
        arsincludegraphics,ExecuteOptions,PackageWarning,textcolor,%
        MessageBreak,ars@@includegraphics,ifcld@backref,rofoot,formatchapter,%
        if@twoside},
        commentstyle=\color{Emerald}\ttfamily,%
        frame=lines}

\lstset{basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily}
\lstset{flexiblecolumns=true}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\normalfont\itshape]{/*}{*/}}}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily}
\lstset{flexiblecolumns=false}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\ttfamily]{!?}{?!}}} 
\lstset{escapeinside={£*}{*£}}
\lstset{firstnumber=last}
\lstset{moredelim={[is][\ttfamily]{!?}{?!}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\pacchetto}[1]{{\normalfont\ttfamily#1}%
\index{Pacchetto!#1@\texttt{#1}}%
\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\bibtex}{\textsc{Bib}\TeX%
\index{bibtex@\textsc{Bib}\protect\TeX}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\amseuler}{\protect\AmS{} Euler%
\index{AmS Euler@\protect\AmS~Euler}%
\index{Font!AmS Euler@\protect\AmS~Euler}}

\lstnewenvironment{code}% 
{\setkeys{lst}{columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true}%
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}%
}{}

\lstset{extendedchars} 
\lstnewenvironment{sidebyside}{% 
    \global\let\lst@intname\@empty 
    \setbox\z@=\hbox\bgroup 
    \setkeys{lst}{columns=fullflexible,% 
    linewidth=0.45\linewidth,keepspaces=true,%
    breaklines=true,% 
    breakindent=0pt,%
    boxpos=t,%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily
}% 
    \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}% 
}{% 
    \lst@EndWriteFile\egroup 
        \begin{center}% 
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}% 
                \hbox to\linewidth{\box\z@\hss} 
            \end{minipage}% 
            \qquad 
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}%
            \setkeys{lst}{frame=none}% 
                \leavevmode \catcode`\^^M=5\relax 
                \small\input{\jobname.tmp}% 
            \end{minipage}% 
        \end{center}% 
} 

\newcommand{\omissis}{[\dots\negthinspace]}

\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}

\hyphenation{Robert Bring-hurst DejaVu
Bera Mono Vera Classic-Thesis suite Knuth Zapf}

\newcommand{\meta}[1]{$\langle${\normalfont\itshape#1}$\rangle$}
\lstset{escapeinside={£*}{*£}}


\DeclareRobustCommand*{\miktex}{MiK\TeX%
\index{miktex@MiK\protect\TeX}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\metafont}{\MF%
\index{METAFONT@\protect\MF}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\metapost}{\MP%
\index{METAPOST@\protect\MP}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\texlive}{\TeX{}~Live%
\index{texlive@\protect\TeX{}~Live}%
}


% ********************************************************************
% biblatex
% ******************************************************************** 

\bibliography{Bibliography}


\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
\cleardoublepage
\manualmark
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\chapter*{\bibname\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}
{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}}}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}


% ********************************************************************
% other commands
% ******************************************************************** 

\newcommand{\ita}[1]{% 
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{italian}#1\end{otherlanguage*}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\pkgname}[1]{{\normalfont\sffamily#1}%
\index{Package!#1@\textsf{#1}}%
\index{#1@\textsf{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\envname}[1]{{\normalfont\ttfamily#1}%
\index{Environment!#1@\texttt{#1}}%
\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\optname}[1]{{\normalfont\ttfamily#1}%
\index{Option!#1@\texttt{#1}}%
\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\clsname}[1]{{\normalfont\sffamily#1}%
\index{Class!#1@\textsf{#1}}%
\index{#1@\textsf{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cmdname}[1]{\mbox{\lstinline!\\#1!}%
\index{#1@\texttt{\hspace*{-1.2ex}\textbackslash#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\classicthesis}{Classic\-Thesis}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\arsclassica}{{\normalfont\sffamily ArsClassica}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\miktex}{MiK\TeX%
\index{miktex@MiK\protect\TeX}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\texlive}{\TeX{}~Live%
\index{texlive@\protect\TeX{}~Live}}
```

and in Bibliography:

```
%*******************************************************
% Bibliography
%*******************************************************
%\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

and in Bibliography.bib:

```
@book{bringhurst:elements,
    author    = {Bringhurst, Robert},
    title     = {The Elements of Typographic Style},
    publisher = {Hartley \& Marks},
    year      = {1992},
    location  = {Point Roberts, Washington, USA}
}
```

However when I use `\cite{bringhurst:elements}` it is only citing the keywords, as follow: [image]

Please help me to change this to a normal author, year citation.

Comment: Are you running the extra tool that generates the needed bibliography data?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Are you running biber and does that run produce any sensible warning or error messages? Are you using an editor and if yes, which one?

Comment: Have a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). What you are seeing suggests that you failed to run Biber. [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) tells you how to make your editor run Biber for you. If you managed to run Biber, you will find a `.blg` file. If there is something wrong with your bibliography, complaints should be logged to that file. See also [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run Biber on your file? Did it work? Did you get any errors in the `.blg` file?