# Bibliography on different systems is empty

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a problem. I'm working on my document on MacOS using prepared template. The problem i to generate bibliography. During compilation error occur - Bibliography empty. Here is my configuration:

```
\usepackage[
style=numeric,
sorting=none,
language=autobib,
autolang=other,
urldate=iso8601,
backref=false,
isbn=true,
url=false,
maxbibnames=3,
backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

I tryied backend as biber and mpm --install and --update both biber and bibtex does not working. Can anyone help ? Thanks

Comment: Did you run Biber (or BibTeX since you have `backend=bibtex`- you should really use `backend=biber` and run Biber, though)? [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Read [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) to find out how to make your editor run Biber for you. If you ran Biber there should be a `.blg` file. What does it say? [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).

Comment: I have filename.tex and call:
- pdflatex filename (bibliography empty)
- bibtex filename  
- pdflatex filename (bibliography empty)

Nothing happens i am still getting pdf file without bibliography

Comment: removed tag `[tex-core]`; an error in that realm could occur only if there is actually some input to process, but here the problem is that none is found.

Comment: I dont have [tex-core] anyware. How can i remove it?

Comment: What does the `.blg` file say?

Comment: It contains: `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: praca.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: rozdzial2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: rozdzial1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: rozdzial3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: rozdzial4.aux
Database file #1: praca-blx.bib
Database file #2: bibliografia.bib
Biblatex version: 3.8`

Comment: Looks OK. The files mentioned there are, however, not the ones in the code snippet you showed. `bibliografia.bib` vs `mybib.bib`. Which do you want? Are you sure you have the right `.bib` files.

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant bibliografia.bib. I change files during pasting listing in my main question. So file names are all right

Answer (score 0):

It started working when i added `\nocite{*}` before printing bibliography. Earlier i had it but i did not compile it using console only texmaker that was probably the reason why it did not occured. After that i `ctrl + z` my file and i was trying to compile it by bibtex without `nocite`.

Comment: `\nocite{*}` (with curly brackets) would be correct.