# BibLatex not producing the right output

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to get BibLatex to work on my MacTex installation. I'm using [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX) tutorial over at sharelatex.com.

They give the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get something different from them. They get

[image]

but I get

[image]

Note mine has no references section, and my citations aren't written the same.

**Possibilities**

1. It's not finding my `.bib` file. I notice that MacTex didn't create the file `~/Library/texmf` for me. I tried creating it myself, and putting my bib file in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/`. I'm not sure how to tell if this is working or not. I assume it would complain if it couldn't see my bib file, but maybe not.
2. biblatex isn't installed properly. I did just update tlmgr and updated biblatex.

**Added:** In response to a question, here is what my "pdfTeX" field says:
Tex:pdftex --file-line-error --synctex=1
Latex:pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1

Here is what my "TeX + divps + distiller" field says:
Tex: simpdftex etex --maxpfb --extratexopts "-file-line-error -synctex=1"
Latex: simpdftex latex --maxpfb --extratexopts "-file-line-error -synctex=1"

Comment: Have you run `biber` between two latex runs?

Comment: This possibly means that you don't compiled correct the file(s). You have to run 1) pdflatex mainfilename 2) bibtex mainfilename 3) twice pdflatex mainfilename (Where twice is not a command and mainfilename doesn't need extension [e.g. from tha file "main.tex"\ you need only "main")

Comment: @koleygr My main file is called "Playing-with-biblio.tex". When I do the second command `bibtex ~/.../Playing-with-biblio` it says `I couldn't open file name /.../Playing-with-biblio.blg`. In fact, I don't know of any such file, and I don't know what that means.

Comment: may be you have to run biber instead of bibtex (I haven't installed this right now) . It was my mistake the bibtex command see here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber/287811) Sorry for that...

Comment: @SergeiGolovan @koleygr I've tried doing both the biber and the biblatex ones, between two pdflatex runs. I omitted the `.tex` at the end of the main file name. Most recently the biber one gave me the error `Cannot find control file '/Users/ericauld/Desktop/Latex test/Playing-with-biblio.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`

Comment: @SergeiGolovan @kolegyr I have in fact passed the `backend=biber` command. (And also tried it without)

Comment: Wild guess: try to put your source files into a directory without spaces in it. LaTeX sometimes breaks for such directories or file names.

Comment: Also you could try a sharelatex or overleaf run to make sure that your installation is ok

Comment: I made a video tutorial on the first steps with biblatex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ. I also had a hard time, in my LaTeX beginning, to understand the stuff "just" from reading, theerfoire I made this video.

Comment: Delete all temporary files. Then run (pdf)LaTeX on your file. If there are any errors, correct them (warnings about undefined references and rerun requests can be ignored for now, everything else needs to be addressed). Check that in the same directory as your `.tex` file there is now a `.bcf` file. Then run Biber. Biber should now find the `.bcf` file, the `.blg` file should contain any other warnings and errors you need to worry about. Then run (pdf)LaTeX twice again.

Comment: Is you `.bib` file called `sample.bib`?

Comment: @cfr No, I altered the code accordingly

Comment: Any news here? Could you get things to work? It would be extremely helpful for us if you could follow the steps outlined in my last comment and show us the warnings and errors from the `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: @moewe I'm sorry, I've gotten distracted. I will try it and let you know how it goes

Comment: Did you get anywhere? It's hard to offer helpful hints if we know only part of the symptoms and not even what exactly you tried.

Comment: Any news here? Did you have some more time to look into this?

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber @moewe I made some changes today. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Johannes_B `\DeclareLanguageMapping` should not be needed in current versions of `biblatex-apa`. Other than that it's pretty solid. There are lots more things to be said, and I would probably always load `babel` and `csquotes` with `biblatex`, but if we start with that, the page size would explode.

Comment: Any news here? It's been more than a month now since you asked the question. We are still missing crucial bits of information here. At the moment the question is unclear. And I will vote to close as such if the question is not updated.

Comment: @moewe I am very sorry. I will update it today.

Comment: @moewe I deleted all the files except the `.tex` file (I'm not sure which ones that TeXShop creates are the temporaries.) When I run `pdflatex`, it tells me `No file Playing-with-biblatex.bbl`. That is not even one of the files I had deleted. Further, it is spitting out the `.log` and `.bcf` files in another directory, namely `/users/ericauld`. So I'm not sure if I should fix these issues before running `biber`.

Comment: If the temporary files are written to `/users/ericauld` instead of the working directory that is a potential problem. I assume you use TeXshop to call TeX? Can you show us a screenshot of the compilation settings? Please copy and paste the value of the most important fields, so that we can see the complete value in case it is cut off in the picture. You can try if your installation is OK by running `pdflatex foo`, `biber foo`, `pdflatex foo`, `pdflatex foo` from the command line (assuming your `.tex` file is called `foo.tex`).

Comment: @moewe Sure. I really appreciate all your help. Here's the screenshots. https://www.sendspace.com/file/n8ahyo

Comment: I'd need to see the full text of the 'pdfTeX' and 'pdfLaTeX' fields. Please copy the contents and edit them into your question. I also noticed that the default bibliography engine is set to BibTeX. How do you call Biber with that setting? (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) Can you compile from the command line as suggested in one of my earlier comments?

Comment: Any news here? Can you tell us what exactly your settings are? Please try compiling from the command line, so we can find out whether your editor messes things up or if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @moewe I couldn't find the "pdfLaTeX" field; only the "pdfTeX" field. I edited my answer with the content of those fields. I also tried compiling from the command line. When I said `biber <filename>`, it told me it couldn't find the bcf file, and asked whether I passed the `backend=biber` command to BibLatTeX. (I went back and made sure that option was written in the TeX file, and the message still came up.) It's still putting the .bcf and .log files in that other directory when I compile from the command line.

Comment: Very, very odd. Is the PDF sent to `/users/ericauld` as well? Is the directory of your `.tex` file writeable? What does `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFOUTPUT` return if you type it in the command line? The fact that temporary files are sent to the wrong directory is definitely the problem here. The question is why that happens. It should not happen if the system has write access to the directory with the `.tex` file and you only call `pdflatex foo` without further options. Did you at some point change settings to allow for a separate build directory or to send temporary files elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, one thing. When you did `pdflatex <filename>` were you in the directory of filename? Or did you say `pdflatex ~/full/path/to/file`? You must be in the directory of the file for things to work properly, i.e. `cd ~/full/path/to` and then `pdflatex file`.

Comment: OK, so once I navigate to the correct file and do those four commands in sequence, the right thing is produced! That's a great milestone, and I thank you for helping me reach it. Now to make it work from TeXShop...when I try to make another file and do it from TeXShop, it tells me to please (re)run Biber and compile again. How might I get it to save the temporary files to the right place? Thanks

Comment: If you run the sequence `pdflatex document`, `biber document`, `pdflatex document`, `pdflatex document` do you get a complete document with citations and bibliography? Does Biber give an error? If everything is fine, double check with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/ that your editor is set up correctly. If it is, it should be fine. In the screenshots you posted a while ago your editor is set up to use BiBTeX by default, which means you need a magic command to make it use Biber. See the link.

Comment: It's me again. Did you get any further here?

Comment: @moewe Thanks very much for keeping up with me on this. Yes, if I run those four commands from the command line, I get a complete document with citations and bibliography. Biber didn't seem to give me any errors. Now, as for compiling from TeXShop, I have changed the option you mention from BiBTeX to Biber, but still I can't get TeXShop to produce a file with citations.

Comment: To answer some of your above questions: as of now, TeXShop seems to be spitting out the `.log` and `.bcf` files in the right place. When I type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFOUTPUT` into the command line, it just thinks for a second, does nothing, and takes me back to the prompt. And no, I have never changed settings to allow for another build directory or to send temp files somewhere else.

Comment: OK, that means that your system is installed correctly and works fine. The problem must be with TeXshop and its compilation settings. The settings also look OK to me. Would it be OK to try and reset the TeXshop settings to default?

Comment: @moewe Sure. I set everything to default, and the problem persists. I also tried everything default except changing `bibtex` to `biber` in the `BibTeX engine` field.

Comment: @moewe I believe all the fields are the same as I wrote in the end of the question.

Comment: @moewe Any idea how I could fix this? Thanks for your help so far, btw

Comment: Not really, sorry. I think we have established that you can compile the documents fine from the command line. So the issue is not with your general installation. The issue must lie with your editor's settings. Now I don't have a Mac and don't use TeXShop, but to my untrained eyes your settings look OK. That's all I can do.