# bibliography stopped working

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am fairly new to Latex. I have googled that and saw 300 different responses and not really helped me.

My text was compiling previously with no major issues but now all my bibliography references are appearing like the label in the bib file.

I deleted the aux file due to one of the posts I saw, maybe that's the reason.

This is how it appears: "...specially in coastal zones (guannel16)."

My file header looks like that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.5cm] 
{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%codification of the document
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\usepackage[autocite=inline, maxbibnames=20, citestyle=authoryear,                         
bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\addbibresource{referenceRP.bib}
```

And the output is all citation (...) undefined.

Comment: You need to run biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: If running Biber does not help, we need to see the log file that Biber produces. Please add the contents of the `.blg` file to your question (Windows classifies `.blg` files as "Performance Manitor Files", but the `.blg`s produced by Biber are just plain text files you can open with your favourite editor).

Comment: I can't find the .blg file, where is it? Running biber didn't help

Comment: The `.blg` file should be in the same directory as your main `.tex` file and your `.log` file. On Windows you may have to make sure that file extensions are not hidden with. If you have run Biber and you don't get a `.blg` file, something is going seriously wrong. Can you run Biber from the command line/terminal? What does `biber --version` give you? Please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 carefully.

Comment: That's the result from my .blg file:                                         
[0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[0] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'ResearchProposal.blg'
[33] biber-MSWIN64:303> INFO - === 
[63] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading 'ResearchProposal.bcf'
[144] Utils.pm:180> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.10) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
[145] Biber.pm:113> INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: As `ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3. This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.10) versions are incompatible.` says: Your versions of `biblatex` and Biber are incompatible. Update your TeX system. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864

Comment: If you use MikTeX you will have to update in both Admin and user mode. To be sure that everything is updated, run the updating steps twice in each mode. If you use TeX live, you'll want to use `tlmgr`. Please let us know if the update worked for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to update but it didn't work. So I uninstall Miktex and the editor. Now biber version is 2.11 and biblatex version is 3.11. According to the docummentation they are compatible and so should work, but still isn't. bbl file is blank

Comment: What does the `.blg` say now?

Comment: Nothing, it's empty

Comment: Can you run Biber from the command line? Does `biber --version` really return 2.11?

Comment: Yes, it does. And returns 2.11

Comment: OK, can you please double check your editor configuration with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Yes, sure. I have done this procedure before but it's still not working. That's what .bbl file says: \begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nyt/global//global/global}
    \entry{adams16}{article}{}
      \name{author}{12}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,uniquepart=base,hash=4255bba08a471a949bdeb52b24c5aece}{%
           family={Adams}... and then keeps showing the references

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm done with that...losing too much time. Can I found an alternative to biber/biblatex?

Comment: IT's working now! I changed the backend to bibtex8

Comment: What you have shown above is the `.bbl` file and it looks OK so far. We need to see the `.blg` file produced by Biber. You can try and use BibTeX8, but you will have to live with a reduced set of features.

Comment: Did you try with Biber or did you decide to stick with BibTeX?

Comment: It's working with biber now. That link you sent me to update biber wasn't working properly. I had to upload MikTex and then upload biber. Then I got another error message, but it just took me to delete the aux file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a version conflict with `biblatex` and Biber that has finally been resolved.