# How can I use biblatex in latextools for sublime text?

Tags: biblatex, latextools

I am trying build this file:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author = {Albert Einstein},
  title = {the true about tree},
  journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
  year = {1905},
  volume = {322},
  number = {10},
  pages = {891-921}
 }
 \end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
% \usepackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}%

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\textcite{einstein} fez um bom trabalho. 
As pessoas precisam de ajuda \cite{einstein}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I am using LatexTools package for Sublime Text and I getting this message:

> Compiling /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex]
>
> Basic Builder:
>
> running pdflatex...done.
>
> running biber...done.
>
> running pdflatex...done.
>
> running pdflatex...done.
>
> No errors. Warnings:
>
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex: LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./main.bib'.
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex:26: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'einstein' on page 1 undefined on input line 26.
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex:27: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'einstein' on page 1 undefined on input line 27.
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex:29: LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 29.
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex: LaTeX Warning: There were   undefined references.
> - /home/bismarck/exemplo/main.tex: Package biblatex Warning:  Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)                main(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
>
> [Done!]

My get a pdf file, but without reference page. What am I doing wrong?

**blg file**:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 482 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: It looks ok. But you got some instructions there, I can only repeat "Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) main(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

Comment: Is there a `/home/bismarck/exemplo/main.blg`? Or any other `.blg` file? If so, what does it say? Everything you show so far looks OK, Biber is reported as being run. That is what normally goes wrong for people with similar problems. Just to make sure double check with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Any news here? Could you find the `.blg` file?

Comment: Any news here? Could you get Biber up and running? Is there a `.blg` file that would help us? See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 for troubleshooting advice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I am having some conflicts with biber and biblatex. How can I install biber 2.4 using apt-get?

Comment: Are you sure you are running biber, and not bibtex?

Comment: I guess you are, I can reproduce your errors and blg file if I run bibtex instead of biber. I think you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220501/105447.

Comment: The `.blg` shows that you are not running Biber, you are definitely running BibTeX. So the `running biber...done.` in the log from the "basic builder" is at least misleading if not an outright lie. Make sure that Biber is run: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: So what about this question? Is it "solved"? What could we do to answer it?

Comment: Solved. My problem was biber version. Just updated biber. Thank you.