# How can I install biblatex-abnt in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: biblatex, biber, abnt

How can I install [biblatex-abnt](https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/tree/master) (style for biblatex)?

I am getting some erros:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-abnt/bbx/abnt.bbx:27: Undefined control sequence. [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix]
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-abnt/bbx/abnt.bbx:27: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-]
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-abnt/bbx/abnt.bbx:235: Undefined control sequence. [\DeclareSortingTemplate]
```

My biber is 2.4 and it is required 2.8. How can I upgrade my biber?

How can I update my biblatex too? (I don't know my version)

Comment: Did you install your TeX distribution via apt-get? Or did you get a ['vanilla' TeX live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) from tug.org? With a vanilla TeX live you can just use `tlmgr` to update your packages. If you are suing the repository version of TeX live you can't really update packages without huge risks.

Comment: I installed via apt-get. I will try vanilla. Thank you.

Comment: I got texlive 2017. But how can I change tex paths? Using "which" command, "pdflatex" if calling from "/usr/bin/pdflatex". How can I change this? I want a calling from "/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex". Or how can I change my texlive path from "/usr/share/texlive/" to "/usr/local/texlive/2017"?

Comment: You should probably uninstall the TeX you got via apt-get. Then you need to follow the instructions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864 to create a 'fake package'. You also need to set your PATH to include `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/`, see https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/57634

Comment: I this also solved as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425497/35864?

Comment: No need to change tex paths, there is an option to create symlinks automatically.

Comment: @BismarckGomes Please consider accepting and upvoting answers to your questions if they helped you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. If the answer did not help you, please leave a comment and explain why. I notice that you have up to now not accepted *any* answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [a 'vanilla' version of TeX live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) you can update and install packages with `tlmgr` (see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)). Remember that TeX live goes through [yearly updating steps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864), so if you can't update at the moment that could be because of the 'development freeze' or because you have an older version of TeX live.

If you have installed a TeX system via your Linux distributions' package repository, you can install additional packages via your distributions' package manager. Often the versions that ship in the OS repositories are a bit behind the current development, so you may end up with older versions and may not be able to install the newest packages.

It may be tempting to install packages manually, but this should generally be avoided. Manual updates of `biblatex` are a bad idea mainly for version dependency issues: The versions of `biblatex` and Biber must match. Additionally, at least `babel`, `polyglossia`, `xstring` must be updated to a matching version (and these packages may come with their own set of dependencies - I believe, however, that this set is not too large). All `biblatex` styles that you use would also have to be updated for the new version of `biblatex`.

A ['vanilla' TeX live installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) seems to be the best solution if you want to use the newest versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-abnt` on a systems that has an older TeX live in its package repository.