# Use of Oscola in a Law Paper

Tags: biblatex, biber, oscola

I am trying to use OSCOLA as referencing style in my legal paper. However, I am not able to get the desirable output. The minimal working example is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=oscola, ibidstyle=uc, ibidtracker=true, backend=biber, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{library}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is an example to learn the use of Oscolla in latex. \cite{Keys2009}.
\end{document}
```

However, only citation key is appeared after the sentence. What I get looks like this. 
[image]

However, I want an output like this.

[image]
[image]

I have also tried `\footcite` but it just places the citation key in the footnote instead of putting complete reference.

Comment: You'll need to run Biber on your document, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for an explanation why (don't worry if the answer mentions BibTeX, the same applies to Biber, but you have to run Biber). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber for you. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 for 'first aid' with Biber.

Comment: Note also that `\addbibresource` should have the full file name. Also, your `\cite` command should here be `\footcite` or `\autocite`.

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem here is that you are not running biber, I think (though as it happens your file cannot be identical to the one you have posted, because the key that is being not found is not called "Keys2009").

But there are some other problems here too:

- `\addbibresource` wants the full `.bib` filename.
- You use `\indexing=cite` but you haven't set up any indexing. This will result is some odd results. If you don't need indexing, don't turn it on. Indexing is complicated to set up, and best to walk before you try to run. When you do want to set it up, check the documentation.
- You use `\cite` when you want a footnote. Use `\autocite` or `\footcite` instead (or put the `\cite` in a footnote yourself).
- The output you want is *not* OSCOLA formatted, so the package won't give you exactly that output. The output that you should get (and the package will give you) is: **Charles W Calomiris, 'The Subprime Turmoil: What's Old, What's New, and What's Next' (2009) 15 Journal of Structured Finance 6.**

I've got a bugfix revision of OSCOLA read to go: it's on github. But I don't think there's anything you are doing which it affects. There's one problem I need to solve before I upload it to CTAN.