# multiple bibliographies same bib file

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a document where I cite all my references and then in the following chapter, I want to cite just some of these references but their numbering should start from [1]. I tried the option "`resetnumbers=true`" but it prints all the references again, as per the MWE below

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,a4paper,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage,pdftex,cleardoubleplain]{scrbook}%abstracton
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex8,,dashed=false,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
bla bla bla \cite{A}, \cite{B}, ..., \cite{Z}

\printbibliography
\chapter{chapter 2}
%% Here I need to reset the bibliography to include references only starting from this point
bla bla bla \cite{B}, \cite{C}

\printbibliography{resetnumbers=true} %only print references B and C with numbers [1] and [2]

\chapter{chapter 3}
%% Here I need to reset the bibliography to include references only starting from this point
bla bla bla \cite{D}, \cite{E}

\printbibliography{resetnumbers=true}%only print references D and E with numbers [1] and [2]

\end{document}
```

Please note I need to use the same command `\cite` everywhere since the document is already written. i.e. I don't want to replace `\cite` with `\citeA` or so as done with the library "`multibib`"

Comment: You should use \refsection to separate the parts/chapters.

Comment: You probably want a `\newrefsection` before each `\chapter`. This can be automated with the `refsection=chapter` option (which had bugs in older versions of `biblatex` and KOMA script). If you use BibTeX (or BibTeX8) you will have to compile several auxiliary files (check the message in the `.log` file), if you switch to Biber (which is a good idea anyway), you can get away with only one Biber run. Lastly `\printbibliography` does not take a mandatory argument, it only has an optional argument, so `\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true]` would be the correct syntax. But that alone won't do ...

Comment: ... you need the different refsections to make sure that each reference gets a new number in each chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I added \newrefsection[References.bib] into my code but then it doesn't print any bibliography after this command. I tried to place it before and after the \chapter but also no result.

Thanks moewe, the parentheses were a typo, I corrected them

Comment: You don't need the optional `[References.bib]` for `\newrefsection`. And as I said you may have to compile different files with BibTeX. Have a look at the `.log` output, it tells you what to do.

Comment: okk, can you tell me how to switch to the biber and would that still have the same IEEE style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `refsection`s to keep the chapters in your document apart.
Using `refsection`s the citations in each chapter are independent of the citations and bibliographies in the other chapters. In particular a `\printbibliography` call will only list those works cited in its `refsection` numbered starting from 1. (That means that the same source can potentially have different numbers in each chapter it is cited.)

You can use `\newrefsection` to start a new `refsection` before each chapter. This can be automated with `refsection=chapter` in the load-time options. There is also `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` in case you prefer to go back to the surrounding `refsection` at the end.

If you stick with `backend=bibtex8` you have to compile several auxiliary files to get the citations right, that can be a little cumbersome. So I suggest you switch to Biber. Have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for background information about BibTeX and Biber.

You will have to change `backend=bibtex8` to `backend=biber` *and* you will have to run Biber instead of BibTeX or tell your editor to do that, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

The change from BibTeX to Biber does not change the style you use, it just allows you to use all of `biblatex`'s features and not just a limited subset of them. In case you have problems with Biber, have a look at [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) for first aid.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber, dashed=false, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\chapter{chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum \cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\chapter{chapter 2}
Dolor sit \cite{nussbaum,worman}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\chapter{chapter 3}
Amet consectur \cite{geer,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

compiled with

```
pdflatex smrdoc
biber smrdoc
pdflatex smrdoc
pdflatex smrdoc
```

will output

[image]

for the bibliography of chapter two.