# How to compile a LaTex document with different chapters but one common references list for the whole document?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texshop

I am referring to https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_4):_Bibliographies_with_BibLaTeX for creation of a Thesis Document in LaTeX through TexShop.

My LaTeX document has several chapters like Introduction, Methodology, etc. I have created a references file `references.bib` in the same directory as the main file `main.tex`. Now, I have citations present in the `references.bib` file and I have cited each citation in the corresponding chapters at places they appear, eg. in Introduction cited paper1 as `\cite{paper1}`, in Introduction cited paper2 as `\cite{paper2}`, cite paper3 in Methodology as `\cite{paper3}` etc. The references in the `references.bib` file are in the following format:

```
@article{paper1,
    author        = {Albert Einstein},
    title         = {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper. (German) [On the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
    journaltitle  = {Annalen der Physik},
    year          = {1905},
    volume        = {322},
    number        = {10},
    pages         = {891-921},
    doi           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}

@online{paper2,
    author        = {Donald Knuth},
    title         = {Knuth: Computers and Typesetting},
    year          = {1984},
    url           = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html}
}

@book{paper3,
    author        = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title         = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
    year          = {1993},
    publisher     = {Addison-Wesley},
    location      = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
```

I am now stuck in the situation that how I can compile the references and generate the `main.tex` LaTex file so that I have one final list of bibliography for the entire document (means references 1-3) after the conclusion section of the thesis. I am using the following for this purpose at the beginning of document:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

And this for displaying references at the place I need them to be i.e. after the Conclusion Section.

```
\printbibliography
```

I am able to compile the LaTeX `main.tex` file easily and the whole document generates without the references, but when I try to do BibTeX on the `main.tex file`, I get the following errors:-

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

I am new to using LaTeX, referred to other documentation as well but still am confused including the website I mentioned which I am primarily referring to. I would really appreciate if you could kindly help me with this. Cheers and Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to run `biber`, not `bibtex` because `\usepackage{biblatex}` is the same with `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`.  You can try `backend=bibtex` but I suggest to use `biber` ...

Comment: @Joyjit Chatterjee please add a fully compilable `MWE` instead of links that redirects to internal websites.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are doing, because your question does not include a short example document (a so-called MWE/MWEB, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/ and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/), but from what I have seen so far I would guess that you need to tell your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. In case you don't know or are interested https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly what BibTeX and Biber do. If you are still having issues after reading the links, we need to see an MWE.

Comment: Thanks its alright. Kurt's answer worked brilliantly. I used backend = bibtex and was able to compile the main.tex file with all references in place.

Comment: @JoyjitChatterjee If at all possible consider switching to `backend=biber` (and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Biber is more powerful than BibTeX and has been the default backend of `biblatex` for quite some time. BibTeX is considered a 'legacy backend' and supported for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using the line

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

you need to run `biber` instead `bibtex`.  It is the same if you use

```
 \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

because `backend=biber` is default option. You can try `backend=bibtex` to call `bibtex` but I suggest to use `biber`.

Comment: Just to add that usually switching to Biber should be as easy as using `backend=biber` and telling one's editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Thanks @moewe , so basically, is using backend = biber going to be significantly different than telling my editor to run Biber instead of BibTex? Actually, I checked the Typeset menu but couldn't find Biber in that. Do I need to install a package etc. to use Biber. I have BibTex and LaTex with a few other options in the typeset menu in TexShop.

Comment: @JoyjitChatterjee Yes, it is different. These are two steps of the process of switching to Biber. Step one is to tell `biblatex` that you would like to use Biber, that is done with `backend=biber` (or by omitting the option entirely, since `backend=biber` is the default, but I prefer to set the `backend` option explicitly). Step two is to tell your *editor* to run Biber (cf. the link). Steps three to `$n$` would be to try to compile a document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, to make sure that Biber is installed if that does not work and follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864