# LaTex will not include reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a project in LaTex, and when I'm inserting a reference, it will not work. The name I named in the bib-file only gets into the pdf in bold.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, textfont=it}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12}}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And my bib-file looks like this:

```
@article{t,
  title = {Technological Aspects of β-Carotene Production},
  journal = {Food and Bioprocess Technology},
  volume = {4},
  number = {5},
  pages = {693-701},
  year = {2011},
  issn = {19355149, 19355130},
  author = {Ribeiro, Bernardo Dias and Barreto, Daniel Weingart and Coelho, Maria Alice Zarur}
}
```

And then the t will appear in the pdf in bold, when I use `~autocite{t}`. Furthermore in my main I entered: `\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]`

Comment: have you run biber to generate the bibliography?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just run from the command line `biber name-of-you-tex-file`. But there's probably  a simpler way from your editor (the details depend on the editor). The  normal cycle is `(pdf)latex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`.

Comment: The preamble snippet loads `biblatex` twice with conflicting options. This should produce an error. You should load the package only once. More generally, the preamble loads a lot of packages. Do you need all of them? Do you know why you load each package? I also find the loading order of some of the packages a bit unusual, but you should probably be fine as long as `hyperref` is loaded last (as it is at the moment).

Comment: If you are having trouble running Biber have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for some background.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines of the preamble snippet will produce the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package biblatex.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

This is the typical message you get when you load a package twice with conflicting options. In general it is best to **avoid loading packages multiple times**.

Replace

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

with a single `\usepackage` instruction loading `biblatex` with the desired options. Say

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

After you have fixed the preamble you should remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and re-compile with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on getting your editor to run Biber for you. [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) can be an entry point to troubleshoot simple Biber issues.

---

With that error resolved, you might get a second error when you cite the entry `t` with pdfLaTeX

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character β (U+03B2)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

The raw β in the title can not be handled by `inputenc` by default. This is not an issue if you use a Unicode engine (XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX). With pdfLaTeX you could help LaTeX along with

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B2}{\ensuremath{\beta}}
```

or using the `textgreek` package

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B2}{\textbeta}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B2}{\textbeta}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{t,
  author  = {Ribeiro, Bernardo Dias and Barreto, Daniel Weingart
             and Coelho, Maria Alice Zarur},
  title   = {Technological Aspects of β-Carotene Production},
  journal = {Food and Bioprocess Technology},
  volume  = {4},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {693-701},
  year    = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,t}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography]