# Biber not running - located in PATH, no error messages with compilation, biber --help produces no output

Tags: biblatex, biber

On MS Windows 10, 64 bit, recent TeXlive instalation, I am unable to run Biber. I am using TeXWorks for compilation. When biber is called, it produces no output in console and running `lualatex biber lualatex` produces same output as running only `lualatex`.

- Biblatex v. 3.14
- Biber from TeXlive 2019

Searching with `where biber` in windows cmd line, I get correct location of instalation:

`C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\biber.exe`

same binary is also used in TeXworks as compilation tool.

According to answer here:

[Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286706/troubleshooting-for-biber)

issuing in cmd line

`biber --help`

produces no output whatsoever (no webpage, no error). How can I resolve this situation? How can I reinstall Biber, preferably via tlmgr? This issue is present on my Office PC (at work), so I might not be able to tinker with TeXlive installation fully.

As MWE (in case content of `.aux` files or so is required) could work example from Overleaf tutorial:

https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%citations

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display bibliography divided into sections, 
depending of citation type. 
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 
Next, \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Donald 
Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}, \textit{The Comprehensive Tex Archive 
Network} (CTAN) \cite{ctan} are \LaTeX\ related items; but the others Donald 
Knuth's items \cite{knuth-fa,knuth-acp} are dedicated to programming. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to set the environment variable `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` so that it points to a temporary folder for which you certainly have writing rights. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Mrs. Fischer. Testing this may take a while (since I have no rights to create global env. variable). I will contact my Office IT dep. in this matter; which will cause (significant) delay. I report back after I will have any more info/results/questions.

Comment: you don't need a global environment variable. Simply run in a command line `set PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP=path/to/folder` and then `biber --help` to check if it can unpack.

Comment: OK, thank you for clarification. Your solution is working. With commands you provided, (a lot of files) is produced in given path. I tried compilation with generated biber.exe ; it gives now error: `Can't locate PAR.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PAR module) (@INC contains:) at -e line 593.`
Is PAR some Perl module? I have (clean) Strawberry Perl installed.

Comment: Did you try while the environment variable is still set?

Comment: I did not. In next attempt, I did all settings and compilations in one command line session (in my knowledge, that ensures env. var. persistence). From `biber`, I get this output:
INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'MWE.blg'
INFO - Reading 'MWE.bcf'
INFO - Found 7 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'sample.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'sample.bib' to sample.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'sample.bib' for section 0
Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence <D2> at Z:\data\_temp\inc\lib/File/Slurper.pm line 59.

Comment: that sounds like a problem in your bib. Is it really utf8 encoded?

Comment: I found out, that also generating files with `filecontents` is not working. But I have finally obtained output from biber in cmd line session. How can I set it now to be able to compile in TeXworks or with `arara`?

Comment: Try if you can set a user environment variable. Search for "environment variable" in the windows search, normally it offers something for the current account.

Comment: OK, I have set it successfully to folder in my personal storage, generated all the filess within from cmd line just issuing `biber --help`. Afterwards, using generated `biber.exe` in TeXworks leads again to error: `Can't locate PAR.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PAR module) (@INC contains:) at -e line 593.` Using `echo %PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP%` produces correct location, meaning the env. variable should be set OK.

Comment: Try to restart texworks, perhaps it hasn't got the environment variable yet.

Comment: You were right (as pretty much always). It also works with `arara`. Would it be beneficial to create some summary of the process as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please type up an answer (or ask Ulrike to write one if you think her comments helped you to find the answer) so that the question can be marked as solved by your accepting the answer. An answer will also help people with a similar problem as it is saves them from having to go through the comments.

Comment: @moewe I thought I wait some, time, but Mrs. Fischer was kind enough to help me and since there really should be an answer, I post it according to steps that mrs. Fischer guided me through. I am now working extensively with `biber` and `biblatex` on creating custom bibliogaphy driver and citation commands. I have a lot of questions which I hope I will be able to solve with documentation, but if not, I hope my questions will catch your sight and that they could be answered! ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is written according to comments posted by Mrs. Fischer. With her guidance, I was able to solve my issue. This solution is specific to Windows users with user-control enabled (usually a company setting).

It seems, that `biber` during execution requires to be "unpacked." This process is blocked from user-control due to forbidden write location. You should follow these steps (tested on Win10 with user control):

1. Create new `user environment variable` called `PAR_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` and set it to path, where you have guaranteed writing access (somewhere, where you have your own files). I recommend create new empty folder for that.
2. start `cmd.exe` and start command `biber --help`. That executes `biber` and makes it unpack in location, which you have specified. It takes some time and its a lot files, so make yourself a coffee or tee
3. After that, in `cmd` output you will get `biber` help page. That signals it is working.
4. Set compilation tool path in your tex editor (in my case, TeXworks) to path where you "unpacked" `biber` to `biber.exe` file newly created.
5. Test a compilation run, it should work OK.

Comment: Another issue arises on user-administered systems with anti-virus software. Recently, the unpacking process was flagged by `BitDefender` as malicius. For that, ask your Office IT department to employ a scanning exception for the folder in which the "unpacking" takes place.