# biber won't run

Tags: biblatex, biber

I copied the files below from the internet as sample files. The compilation with latex works although there are a lot of warnings, e.g.

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 41.

(main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

However, running biber on the main.tex file does not give any results besides

```
"Process started" and 
"Process exited with error(s)"
```

Below is my main file and bib file. Can anyone help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{biblatex} package}
\author{Share\LaTeX}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display bibliography divided into sections, depending of citation type. 
Let's cite! Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 
Next, \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}, \textit{The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network} (CTAN) \cite{ctan} are \LaTeX\ related items; but the others Donald Knuth's items \cite{knuth-fa,knuth-acp} are dedicated to programming. 

\medskip

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Whole bibliography}
] %Prints the entire bibliography with the titel "Whole bibliography"

\clearpage

%Filters bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Articles only}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books only}]
\printbibliography[keyword={physics},title={Physics-related only}]
\printbibliography[keyword={latex},title={\LaTeX-related only}]

\end{document}
```

My bib file is the following:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: 01.09.2016)",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}
@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

The .blg file Looks like that

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 482 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: If your editor ran Biber for you, you should be able to find a `.blg` file (on Windows system that file might be misclassified as 'performance monitor file', but it is a simple text file you can open with your favourite text editor). Please add its complete contents to the question.

Comment: For the avoidance of any doubt: I just ran your example and it works as expected. So the issue is not the code. It is quite probably an issue with your Biber installation (not installed, version that doesn't match `biblatex`, corrupted cache, ...).

Comment: try `biber --help`; if it doesnt run, than its an installation problem. For that, there are two references on SE: Biber troubleshooting and one question of mine. Note, that if you are on user control on Widows (you dont have admin rights) or you use Miktex distro, you are very likely to have trouble with biber installation (well, from my experience at least).

Comment: Some first-aid hints are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864. We really need to see the `.blg` file to be able to say anything useful that hasn't ben said there.

Comment: You are not running Biber at all: you are running BibTeX!

Comment: As Joseph says: You are running BibTeX when you need to run Biber. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with configuring your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX for you.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to call Biber and produce a working bibliography?

Comment: I managed to call Biber on my private Laptop. However, on my Business Laptop trying to run Biber gives the error message Process started

Process exited with error(s). There might be something wrong with the configuration of Texmaker.