# Biblatex : Sorting in-text citations by year, and bibliography by name?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

How to sort the in-text citations by year, but those of the bibliography by name?

```
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis} % Online template
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true, maxcitenames=1, url=false, doi=false, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\bibliography{mybib}
```

mybib is a bib file that contains:

```
@ARTICLE{neu1984,
   author = {{Neugebauer}, G. and {Habing}, H.~J. and {van Duinen}, R.},
     year = 1984}

@ARTICLE{kes1996,
   author = {{Kessler}, M.~F. and {Steinz}, J.~A. and {Anderegg}, M.~E.},
     year = 1996}
```

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\citealt{neu1984,kes1996}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is sorted chronologically in-text:

[image]

and in the bibliography, it appears sorted chronologically, but i would like it *in alphabatical order*:

[image]

**1) I tried, as suggested in other solutions:**

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=ny]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
```

It says:

> ! LaTeX Error: Environment refcontext undefined.

**2) I tried:**

```
\printbibliography[sorting=ny]
```

It says:

> ! Package keyval Error: sorting undefined.

Answer (score 2):

With a current version of `biblatex` the correct method is to use `refcontext`s, something similar to the method 1 you show in the question. But `refcontext`s only work with Biber as backend, you cannot use BibTeX.

So you need to switch to Biber. In theory that should be as easy as changing `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,` and running – or instructing your editor to run – Biber instead of BibTeX (see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)). (If you having trouble running Biber, have a look at [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864) for first aid. Feel free to ask a new question if you continue having trouble getting Biber to run even after going through that post. Please post the `.blg` file in that case.)

Then it should be enough to give the desired citation sorting `sorting=ynt,` as global option and wrap `\printbibliography` in a new `refcontext` with `sorting=nyt`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  sorting=ynt,
  maxcitenames=1,
  natbib=true,
  url=false, doi=false,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{neu1984,
  author = {Neugebauer, G. and Habing, H. J. and van Duinen, R.},
  year   = 1984,
}
@ARTICLE{kes1996,
  author = {Kessler, M. F. and Steinz, J. A. and Anderegg, M. E.},
  year   = 1996,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{kes1996,neu1984}

\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Neugebauer et al., 1984; Kessler et al., 1996)//Kessler, M. F., J. A. Steinz and M. E. Anderegg (1996). In://Neugebauer, G., H. J. Habing and R. van Duinen (1984). In:]