# Compiler cannot start "biber.exe", unsure why

Tags: biblatex, biber

Previous tex files used bibtex as a backup. I wanted to update this to biber to use a certain cite-style (apa). I have checked the download/updated on Tex Live Utility and changed the settings for commands etc in TexMaker. But when I try to run the file I get the following error message:

Error : could not start the command : "biber.exe" "abc"

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=apa,bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{xyz}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

text text text... \cite{citekey}

\theendnotes
{\singlespacing\printbibliography}
\end{document}
```

I have tried various strategies recommended in other posts---checking downloads, settings for compiler etc---to no avail.

Update: running biber as a standalone command works normally. The problem arises when running the LaTex/biber/LaTex cycle.

Comment: Can you check that you have installed Biber in the TeX Live Utility? Can you try running `biber --version` in the command line? (Some more first-aid hints: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864)

Comment: I have checked some first-aid hints. As per the top answer: biber is installed correctly and the terminal returns the help page. I am not sure if I am running biber correctly, but I don't get the question-mark errors. I was initially get an error because I was running biblatex as a backend but I have fixed this. I have configured TexMaker to run biber. Perhaps my biblatex and bibtex don't match? I just wasn't expecting this error message in that case. ETA: I am running biber version 2.14.

Comment: Can you try to compile your document from the command line (assuming your document is called `mydoc.tex` navigate to the directory in the command line, then run `pdflatex mydoc`, `biber mydoc`, `pdflatex mydoc`, `pdflatex mydoc`)? Double check your editor settings with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. The message your are getting either comes from your OS or your editor. It does not appear to be from Biber or a TeX-related component.

Comment: I cannot compile from the command line. I get the following error: 

```This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `mydoc,'.
<*> mydoc, 
           biber mydoc, pdflatex mydoc, pdflatex mydoc```

I think my editor settings are as required.

Comment: You need to be in the correct folder for this to work (navigate to the folder with `cd` in the command line) and you need to use the name of your main `.tex` file. So `pdflatex mydoc` only works if your document is indeed called `mydoc.tex`.

Comment: I don't understand the use of ```cd``` in the command line. It does not seem to generate any output, just a new line. I have renamed the file ```mydoc.tex``` for simplicity, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: "tex live utility" is on a Mac? is your biber executable really biber.exe not biber ?

Comment: When you open the command line, you are usually not in the folder/directory, where your TeX file is. So you have to move there. This is usually done by typing [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) followed by the a folder path. (I don't know your operating system, so I can't link to any more specific guide. But if you search for your OS and "terminal" on the web you should find many helpful guides telling you about basic terminal usage, `cd`, etc.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I removed the ".exe" from the settings and it now runs without an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you are on a Mac but have an incorrectly ported Windows configuration where the biber executable would be `biber.exe`. executables on Mac and Linux are usually extension-less, so `biber`.