# Adding citations with bibtex

Tags: biblatex

This is in my preambule:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatura.bib}
```

I have a literatura.bib file containing this:

```
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

In main file I have this:

```
\printbibliography
```

And this is how I cite it:

```
\cite{latexcompanion}
```

This produces no bibliography and no results, other than [latexcompanion]  where the citation is placed, which is not clickable.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

.blg output:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: literatura.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file literatura.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file literatura.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file literatura.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 494 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Did you process your compiled LaTeX file with `biber`?

Comment: You are using `biblatex` (with `backend=biber,`) so you need to run Biber on your document and not BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 on how to configure your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX. If you want to know why you need to run Biber (or BibTeX) in the first place, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. For the difference between BibTeX and Biber see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. A full compilation cycle will now involve LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX).

Comment: I've switched to biber in TexMaker and I compile like this: LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, but the output is still the same.

Comment: Are there any errors in the LaTeX run? If you ran Biber correctly, there should be a `.blg` file (on Windows machine you may have to unhide file extensions to see it, Windows may also classify `.blg` files as 'Performance monitor' files or some such, but they are really text files you can open with any text editor). Open the `.blg` file and post its complete content into the question here. Some more first-aid tips are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864.

Comment: I use Ubuntu, there is .blg file. But I found one warning that is "Empty bibliography." on the line where I am \printbibliography. My .bib file is not empty though.

Comment: Open the `.blg` file and post its complete contents here. The "empty bibliography" warning is expected here. The helpful info will be in the `.blg` file.

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: literatura.aux

I found no \citation commands---while reading file literatura.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file literatura.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file literatura.aux

You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 494 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
...
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: I've added full output to the post.

Comment: @vojtak Your posted `.blg` file still shows that you are running `bibtex` and not `biber` on the file.

Comment: As Alan says: The `.blg` file is from a BibTeX run. You need to make sure to run Biber and not BibTeX on your file. If you compile manually from the command line (or via a script), change your `bibtex <filename>` call to `biber <filename>`. If you are using an editor refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 explains the difference between Biber and BibTeX. See also my first comment.