# Using Biblatex with a .bib file not citing properly

Tags: biblatex, citing, thesis

I'm trying to compile the bibliography for my thesis using biblatex. However, when I use the recommended syntax and code from the biblatex user guide, the citations I'd like in parentheses come out displaying the citation key I used for the source in my .bib file.

For example, it will look like:

"Blah, blah, blah, blah (chase1985whole), blah, blah, blah."

Instead of:

"Blah, blah, blah, blah (Chase, 1985), blah, blah, blah."

I'm using `\parencite{chase1985whole}`. Am I simply using it incorrectly? I'm just copying tutorial videos.

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage
[
        letterpaper,
        left=3.81cm,
        right=2.56cm,
        top=2.56cm,
        bottom=2.56cm
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{times}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

and my .bib citation key:

```
@article{chase1985whole,
  title={Whole vessels and sherds: an experimental investigation of their quantitative relationships},
  author={Chase, Philip G},
  journaltitle={Journal of Field Archaeology},
  volume={12},
  number={2},
  pages={213--218},
  year={1985},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Could it be a directory issue?

Comment: Are you sure, you compile using `biber` instead of `bibtex`, which would be the default behaviour of the `biblatex` package. This is something you need to change in your editor.

Comment: Alternatively, add the `backend=bibtex` option to the `biblatex` package, which should work.

Comment: @MarkusG. With `style=apa,` Biber is required. Adding `backend=bibtex,` gives the error `! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.` And even if it did work, Biber is usually the better choice.

Comment: You need to run Biber (and not BibTeX) on your file, so that a full compilation cycle at least runs LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX in that order (here "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...; with your preamble [`fontenc`] most likely pdfLaTeX). If you compile your document via an editor, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with getting your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: ... If you have already configured your editor to run Biber for you (or run Biber manually) and still don't get the desired output, show us the `.blg` file (Biber's log file, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864).