# How to generate a bibliography in the APA style while using biblatex (no biber)?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, bibliographystyle

I am struggling to find a way to generate a bibliography in the APA style while using biblatex with backend=bibtex, not biber (otherwise a bunch of other errors show up). I am using TeXstudio. My code is the following:

```
%\listfiles
\documentclass[a5paper,10.22pt,twoside,openany]{book}



\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[a5paper,top=1in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authoryear,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

...........................................................

\chapter*{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[
heading=none,
heading=bibintoc,
heading=subbibliography,
title={Scientific books and papers},
keyword=science
]


\printbibliography[
heading=none,
heading=bibintoc,
heading=subbibliography,
title={Legislative texts},
keyword=law
]

\printbibliography[
heading=none,
heading=bibintoc,
heading=subbibliography ,
title={Official documents and reports},
keyword=report
]

\printbibliography[
heading=none,
heading=bibintoc,
heading=subbibliography ,
title={Websites},
keyword=website
]

\printbibliography[
heading=none,
heading=bibintoc,
heading=subbibliography ,
title={Newspaper articles},
keyword=news
]


\thispagestyle{empty}
\markboth{}{}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to modify it to get an APA bibliography? Thank you very much in advance!!

EDIT: If I configure my editor for biber instead of bibtex as suggested in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations), and I use \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex},
what I get when compiling is (here, I am calling "test.tex" my main file):
INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 93 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bibliography.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'Bibliography.bib'
FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV
Likely your .bib has a very bad entry which causes libbtparse to crash:

Comment: I'm sorry: If you want real APA style with `biblatex` (as implemented by `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,`) you must use Biber. `biblatex-apa` will complain if you try and use BibTeX with `backend=bibtex,` as some of its features will not work with BibTeX. What problems did you have with Biber?

Comment: Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with configuring your editor for Biber. If you get errors, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 and/or post the `.blg` and `.log` files here. Try a small example document like https://gist.github.com/moewew/3de6d1d34d608cac03ae6b148b3756a4 first (this example should be compilable without any change the `.bib` file loaded there is available and will be found automatically on all systems with `biblatex`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @moewe. I have edited my main question since I had not enough space in the comment, do you have any ideas about how to fix my problem?

Comment: Please trim your example code to include *only* code that shows the problem. We don't need to see all the packages you've loaded or all the redefinitions of sections. The `\addbibresource` command requires the file extension, so you must use `\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}`.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn, I've trimmed my code.

Comment: Thanks, this is better, but it's clear from the error that you likely have a mal-formed `.bib` entry. You should not use `citestyle=authoryear` with the `apa` style (which is already an author year style). But to diagnose this you will need to either inspect your `.bib` file manually looking for e.g. missing commas between fields, etc. or selectively comment out citations to find which entry is failing.

Comment: Any news here? The error message clearly complains about your `.bib` file, so that is where you should look for the error. If you can't share your `.bib` file with us, though, we can't really give any more useful hints than: Try binary search (i.e. delete half of your file until you find the problematic entry).