# Bibliography won't show using JabRef

Tags: bibliographies, jabref

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Library}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=30mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
```

Comment: `JabRef` is just a management system for `bib` files but isn't directly related to TeX. Are you running `pdflatex`+`bibtex`+`pdflatex`+`pdflatex`?

Comment: It could be because I haven't done that. I just tried it now, and it is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, "not working" is a too generic statement to debug. Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4408/82917), clarify how your are compiling your code, and show exactly what is wrong with the output.

Comment: I edited the code. The output doesn't show the References.

Comment: You have completely changed your code, which now suggests you are using `biblatex`, so you probably should run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: Just a hint on layout-ing your question: You can mark your code as such by using the curly braces button in the editor. This makes it easier to identify code examples and seperate them from the rest of the text.

Comment: I dont even know the differenceb between biber and bibtex, just I dont think i can use them at the same time. but knowing that doesnt help me solve my problem.

Comment: A short primer about the differences is in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. Both BibTeX and Biber are external tools that need to be run on your document to compile the required references from the `.bib` file (a wonderful explanation is in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). A document with bibliography usually needs to be compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX; it's the same for BibTeX-based bibliographies where you'd run BibTeX instead of Biber). ...

Comment: ... Many editors are set up to run BibTeX (either via some heuristic or manually), so if you are using `biblatex`, you may need to tell your editor to run Biber instead: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If you have issues with Biber, some first-aid tips are at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864.

Comment: Apart from all that `\addbibresource{Library}` would very likely cause an error. `\addbibresource` requires the file name of your `.bib` file *with* file extension. So if the file is called `Library.bib`, you need `\addbibresource{Library.bib}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information. I think that it may even be the "TexMaker" that I am using. Because I switched to another program, I made it work eventually. I still want to find out, how to make it work in the TexMaker, so I am glad I posted here. I almost switched to the Microsoft Word, which I am not too fond of. With the rest of the commands I do have minor issues. Thank you for everyone's alswers!!