# bibliography: how to get numeric numbers instead of strings in citations?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am preparing part of a big latex report in tex studio. In references, I see textual content inside square brackets instead of numeric numbers. Since it is a big report, I cannot paste it here. Can somebody provide some pointers on how to make numeric reference numbers to come in citations?

file: main.tex

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref1.bib}
    ::::

    \chapter{ch01}
    \input{chapters/ch01}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

file: ref1.bib

```
@article{ni2010privacy,
    title       = {Privacy-aware role-based access control},
    author      = {Ni, Qun and Bertino, Elisa and Lobo, Jorge and Brodie, Carolyn and Karat, Clare-Marie and Karat, John and Trombeta, Alberto},
    journal     = {ACM Transactions on Information and System Security (TISSEC)},
    volume      = {13},
    number      = {3},
    pages       = {1--31},
    year        = {2010},
    publisher   = {ACM New York, NY, USA}
}
@inproceedings{masoumzadeh2008purbac,
    title       = {PuRBAC: Purpose-aware role-based access control},
    author      = {Masoumzadeh, Amirreza and Joshi, James BD},
    booktitle   = {OTM Confederated International Conferences" On the Move to Meaningful Internet Systems"},
    pages       = {1104--1121},
    year        = {2008},
    organization    = {Springer}
}
@inproceedings{yang2007purpose,
    title       = {A purpose-based access control model},
    author      = {Yang, Naikuo and Barringer, Howard and Zhang, Ning},
    booktitle   = {Third International Symposium on Information Assurance and Security},
    pages       = {143--148},
    year        = {2007},
    organization    = {IEEE}
}
```

file: chapters/ch01

```
\cite{ni2010privacy}, \cite{masoumzadeh2008purbac}, \cite{yang2007purpose} propose extensions to RBAC. In P-RBAC \cite{ni2010privacy} the privacy policies are incorporated to protect access to private and sensitive data.
```

output:

[image]

Comment: The symptoms you are seeing are consistent with broadly two classes of issues: (1) You did not compile your document with Biber. In order for citations and the bibliography to show correctly your document needs to be compile with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). Biber makes the data from your `.bib` file readable for LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you use an editor to do the compilation for you have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 to make it run Biber. ...

Comment: ... (2) You did run Biber, but your `.bib` file contains faulty entries that cause errors so bad that Biber has to stop reading the file. Errors like this are reported in the `.blg` file. This file will always be there if you ran Biber. If you have no `.blg` file, you are probably in case (1) if you have a `.blg` file, open it and check for warnings or errors. Note that Windows might classify `.blg` files as "performance monitor" files. Furthermore, Windows may hide the file extension from you unless you explicitly tell Windows to show you all file extensions.

Comment: Please refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 for more details.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you don't have to say `\cite{ni2010privacy}, \cite{masoumzadeh2008purbac}, \cite{yang2007purpose}` to cite several sources, you can say `\cite{ni2010privacy,masoumzadeh2008purbac,yang2007purpose}`. If you prefer the look of separate brackets for each citation, look into using `style=numeric-verb,` instead of `style=numeric,` (there is also `style=numeric-comp,` for the 'opposite').

Comment: If you want to test your setup, try to compile the document from https://gist.github.com/moewew/e3e3c128fc17ca7f57ab90604bb6ba4b *without any change*. (That file references the `.bib` file `biblatex-examples.bib`. You **do not** and should not need to create this file. This file is available on all machines on which `biblatex` is installed correctly. It will be found automatically. You can just take the example as posted and run it in a new, empty folder.) If that file compiles fine, your system is correctly set up for Biber. If it does not, you need to check your settings.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run the simple example document I posted above? Could you run Biber?

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of the generic "configure your editor for Biber" question in absence of feedback.