# References are not appearing when using \cite{} in the dissertation neither in the text nor in the Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, thesis

I am using the template provided by my university to write my dissertation. Now the dissertation is done but I'm having a problem with the references. The references are not appearing when using \cite{This_Article} in the text. what is appearing the just the name "This_Article" in the text. Though, I have a file biblio.bib for the references. Also there is no bibliography appearing at the last page at all.
I added the latex code hoping to get some help:

```
\documentclass[english]{amu_these}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,cancel,xcolor,hyperref,comment,graphicx,geometry}
 \usepackage{subfig}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,url,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
 \usepackage{amsthm}


\newtheorem{theoreme}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}[theoreme]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theoreme]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{rem}[theoreme]{Remark}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theoreme]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theoreme]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\proofname{proof}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}


 
\newcommand\xqed[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand\demo{\xqed{$\square$}}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns,scopes,intersections,calc}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx,url,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dsfont}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}
 

 \hypersetup{bookmarks, colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, hyperfigures, pagebackref,
    pdfcreator=LaTeX, breaklinks=true, pdfpagelayout=SinglePage, bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2}
 \chead{}
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Page de titre}{titre}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \input{tex/titre.tex}
                                        %% licence
    \newpage
    \pdfbookmark[0]{Affidavit}{affidavit}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \input{tex/licence}


    

    \chapter*{Abstract}                 %% abstract
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \input{tex/abstract}
    


    \chapter*{Remerciements}            %% remerciements
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remerciements}
    \input{tex/remercie}



    \microtypesetup{protrusion=false}   %% désactive la protrusion (TOC LOFT GLS)
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \tableofcontents                    %% TOC
    \listoffigures                      %% LOF
    \listoftables                       %% LOT
    \printglossary[                     %% Acronymes
        type=\acronymtype,
        title={Liste des acronymes},
        toctitle={Liste des acronymes}
        ]
    \printglossary[                     %% Glossaire
        title={Glossaire},
        toctitle={Glossaire}
        ]
    \printglossary[                     %% Nomenclature
        type=notation,
        title={Nomenclature},
        toctitle={Nomenclature}
        ]
    \microtypesetup{protrusion=true}    %% rétabli la protrusion

    \ohead{\leftmark\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{ -- \rightmark}}    %% place le chapître et la partie en en-tête
\selectlanguage{english}



\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\markboth{List of Symbols}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\input{tex/LOS}
\chapter{ Preliminaries}
    \input{tex/chap0}
    
    \chapter{Chapter2}
    \input{tex/chap2}
    
 \chapter{Chapter3}
\input{tex/chap3}
          
     \appendix

    \newpage
\printbibliography[                 %% bibliographie
heading=bibintoc
    ]   
    
    \chapter*{ANNEXES}
\end{document}
```

this is what I'm getting in the texts: ...the first volume of his book \cite{bennett} on the history of Control Engineering quoting the...
-> the first volume of his book **Bennett** on the history of Control Engineering quoting the

Comment: We don't have `amu_these`, so it is hard to say with certainty, but the `\printbibliography` in your code suggests the class loads `biblatex`. In that case you need to compile your document with Biber to obtain citations and a bibliography. A full compilation run would be LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your preferred flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). See for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 a wonderful explanation of Biber's significance. If you are using an editor to compile your document, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: If you did run Biber and still do not get the expected output, you probably have an error in your `.bib` file. In that case inspect the `.blg` file (Biber's log file). (Note that Windows may classify the `.blg` file as a 'performance monitor' file and may hide its file extension.) See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 for more hints.

Comment: I did pdfLatex, bibtex, pdfLatex, pdfLatex, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Also, I checked the .blg file and this what was written.     This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: these.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file these.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file these.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file these.aux
You've used 0 entries,
""knowing that I already wrote in the code if you can see above, the \printbibliography

Comment: If the `.blg` starts with `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020)` you are running BibTeX, but you code strongly suggests you should be running Biber instead. If you run the commands manually, run Biber (`biber mydoc`) instead of BibTeX (`bibtex mydoc` or `bibtex mydoc.aux`). If you use an editor, configure it as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: The references appear but using \cite{Bennet} in the code it gives **1986** in the text while in the bibliography it gives:  [Ben86] Stuart Bennet.A history of control engineering....**and this makes a confusion when reading the text and looking for the reference in the bibliography because they are named differently. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That just sounds like a very confusing combination of bibliography and citation styles. `biblatex` is not loaded in the code shown so far, so I'm suspecting it is loaded by your class (`amu_these`). You would have to have a look at it. (We can't really help here since we don't know `amu_these`.)