# apacite: Different author name in textcite and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

Just to preface, I'm rather new to LaTeX and even newer to using .bib files to go along with them, but I think I got the basic idea. I'm using MikTeX and TeXMaker on my laptop.

I'd like to cite 3Blue1Brown's YouTube video on the Monster Group. APA style demands that I put his username after his real name in brackets, like so: Sanderson, Grant [3Blue1Brown]...

However, I can't seem to do that with apacite. Here's what I have so far in the .bib file:

```
@misc{3b1bvideo,
    type = {Video},
    author = {Grant Sanderson},
    year = {2020},
    month = {August},
    day = {19},
    title = {Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster},
    howpublished = {YouTube},
    url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE}
}
```

That works really well. It has all the required elements except for the username.

I can get the username in the reference list like this:

```
@misc{3b1bvideo,
    type = {Video},
    author = "{Sanderson, G. [3Blue1Brown]}",
    year = {2020},
    month = {August},
    day = {19},
    title = {Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster},
    howpublished = {YouTube},
    url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE}
}
```

...but then it ruins the in-text citations.

Is there any possible way to put his username in the reference list without ruining the in-text citations? I'd be okay with modifying the .bst files and/or running some \renewcommand lines, so long as they don't mess up the other reference items.

Comment: Unrelated, `month = {August}` is not recommended: You also get a warning because of that (`legacy month field 'August' in entry '3b1bvideo' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.`). See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: I updated your title to better reflect the problem (as I understand it). Let me know if the new title is not correct.

Comment: **Recommendation:** Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407 and prepare a better code example. This makes it easier to understand your situation and makes it less likely that misunderstandings occur.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Note that `apacite` and `biblatex` are two completely different systems. What's more, `biblatex-apa` can be different from the `biblatex` standard styles. I would not edit the title without confirmation from the OP that they actually want a `biblatex` solution as opposed to an `apacite` solution.

Comment: @moewe Good points, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about apacite specifically, my apologies for not being very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see `apacite` has no field or other standard way of giving user names.

Here is a hacky way to get the desired output that exploits how BibTeX generates initials.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{3b1bvideo,
  type         = {Video},
  author       = {Sanderson, {\relax G. [3Blue1Brown]}},
  year         = {2020},
  month        = {August},
  day          = {19},
  title        = {Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster},
  howpublished = {YouTube},
  url          = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{3b1bvideo}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sanderson, 2020) Sanderson, G. [3Blue1Brown]. (2020, August 19). Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster [Video]. YouTube. Retrieved from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE]

Note that `apacite` implements 6th edition APA style (from the 2009 manual). The current 7th edition of the APA manual was published in 2019 and bibliography and citation style differ in some aspects quite significantly from the 6th edition.

If you need 7th-edition APA style, the only LaTeX implementation that I know of is `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,` for `biblatex`. Note that if you want to switch to `biblatex` you need to compile your document with Biber instead of BibTeX ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) can help with that). It might also be instructive to have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) if you are not familiar with `biblatex`.

`biblatex-apa` uses field annotations to specify the user name

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@video{3b1bvideo,
  entrysubtype       = {video},
  author             = {Sanderson, G},
  author+an:username = {1="3Blue1Brown"},
  title              = {Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster},
  publisher          = {YouTube},
  date               = {2020-08-19},
  url                = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,3b1bvideo}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sanderson, 2020; Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) Sanderson, G. [3Blue1Brown]. (2020, August 19). Group theory, abstraction, and the 196,883-dimensional monster [Video]. YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE]

There is a difference in otuput here between `apacite` and `biblatex-apa`. But as far as I can see from https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/youtube-references the output produced by `biblatex-apa` is indeed what 7th edition APA style wants.

Comment: Just as an aside, https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/youtube-references says "Use the name of the account that uploaded the video as the author." which to me suggests that the real name (if it is not equal to the account name) might not have to be given after all. But I don't have the real manual at hand to check the actual wording there to see if that is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will have to look into biblatex, but I don't think my front-end (TeXMaker) supports Biber. I'll have to see if the differences between APA 6th and 7th editions are significant enough to warrant redoing the bibliography section.

Comment: @The_Scientist___ Any IDE that claims to be "for LaTeX" should nowadays have a way to support Biber. As far as I can see TeXmaker is no exception. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 has a guide to have TeXmaker support Biber. Depending on your TeX distribution you may have to install Biber first and you may or may not have to make sure that your Biber and `biblatex` versions match. Common issues are discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864, but for most people "it should just work".