# Latex did not update bbl file with new bib file

Tags: biber, bbl

I have checked the similar question available, still could not fix my problem.
I used a tex template from my classmate who is using Winedt. For my part, I am using MacBook. When I compile it with an updated bib file in the terminal using `xelatex -> biber -> xelatex -> xelatex`, it can not update the bbl file. Must I generate a bbl file using bib file by hand?
Here is the tex file:

```
    \documentclass[
         degree = phd,  %
        ]{njuthesis}
    \njusetup{
        bib = {
            resource = {sample.bib},
            option = {
                gbnamefmt = lowercase,
                backend=biber
            }
        }
}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{listings} %
    
    \begin{document}
    
    sample~\cite{Dine1993}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \printbibliography
    
    \end{document}
```

Here are the compile commands:

```
xelatex sample.tex
biber  sample
xelatex sample.tex
xelatex sample.tex
```

By this [latexsample](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GgEMYnp9gH1K1zuouYFUhstH2vsDFDt5?usp=share_link), you can repeat the problem as I said.

The class is available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/njuthesis).

And when I compile the tex file, it always remind me:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                sample
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on sample.pdf (3 pages).
Transcript written on sample.log.
```

Comment: Welcome, please provide `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: The setup that we can see so far is pretty non-standard, so I can't say anything more concrete about that until I have seen a small, compilable example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Note that such an example document should only reference files that are available to everyone (ideally on CTAN), so try to remove all references to files we don't have.

Comment: For now I can only give generic advice. You can only expect correct output if no errors were reported during your XeLaTeX and Biber runs. Check that XeLaTeX runs without error. If not, fix all errors first (start with the first one, later errors might be knock-on effects). Then run Biber. You should get log output telling you that a `.bbl` file was created. Biber generates its log information in the `.blg` file. Add the complete contents of the `.blg` file to your question. ...

Comment: ... Make sure that the `.bib` file you are editing is actually the `.bib` file that your document is supposed to use. (Check where it is saved.)

Comment: Hi @moewe! Thank you very much! I added a compilable sample.

Comment: Isn’t a comma missing after `lowercase`?

Comment: Hi @egreg! Yes, I have corrected it, thank you very much!

Comment: Ok: Still persistent?

Comment: Hi@MS-SPO!Yes, when compiling, It always remind me rerun biber.

Comment: And did you run Biber? What did it say? What does your `.blg` file say? If you did run Biber, there should be a `.blg` file. Open it and post its complete contents in the question.

Comment: BTW I tried to run your MWE. I didn't want to download `njuthesis` from your external link, but it is on CTAN, so that was no problem. Unless there are known issues with the CTAN version, I strongly recommend you get rid of your local version of the class and use the version provided by your TeX distribution. The CTAN version complained about `! LaTeX Error: Key 'nju/degree' accepts only a fixed set of choices.` and I didn't have the required fonts installed, so I didn't manage to run the example. Anyway, I'm guessing the code is OK and your problems lie elsewhere. ...

Comment: ... As I said above, you need to make sure that XeLaTeX compiles without error and then you need to get hold of the `.blg` file to find out if Biber complains about anything.

Comment: Any news here? We can only help you in a useful way if you share the `.blg` file of the Biber run with us. Otherwise we can only offer generic hints as above or in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of the generic https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864. If more specific information becomes available, we can reopen the question and look at it again. But in its current state it is basically unanswerable except for the generic hints in the duplicate.

Comment: Hi all, just to summarize this problem. Afterward, I just used textstudio to "xelatex " and "biber" the codes, and the problem disappeared. So the suggestion is to choose a good IDE.