# BibLaTeX emits strange error messages

Tags: biblatex, biber, exam

So I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{foo.bib,bar.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah. \cite{source}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And I get these errors:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'source' on page 1 undefined on input line X.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line Y.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex)                file(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I've used this setup before with other documents; I can't figure out why it's not working this time. What could be going on?

(Incidentally, I did try the `[backend=biber]` option with `biblatex`, but the same thing happens.)

Comment: Did you run LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX?

Comment: @JosephWright When I try, I get this error message from Biber:

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'file.tex.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?

(And it looks to me like latex did run successfully.)

Comment: How _exactly_ did you call Biber? The `.tex.bcf` is odd

Comment: You need to call Biber on the basename of your main `.tex` file without the file extension (or explicitly on the `.bcf` file). Assuming your main `.tex` file is called `mydoc.tex`, you need to run `biber mydoc` (or `biber mydoc.bcf`). If you are using an editor to run Biber, make sure it is configured correctly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: @moewe That fixed it (running `biber mydoc`).

Comment: Great! Then this question is a duplicate of the FAQ https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 that explains how to run BibTeX and Biber properly. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 and the already linked https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.