# bibliography problem in latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to make bibliography for my tex. I have written this with ri identifiers in my bib document. but it shows ri in my text. what should I do

```
\documentclass[11pt,times]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\usepackage{sectsty}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
    \small  
    \textit{Keywords:} #1
}
\providecommand{\JEL}[1]
{
    \small  
    \textit{JEL classification:} #1
}

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6in}}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in+6\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=bwl-FU]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sample}
\newtheorem{assum}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{defini}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
    In courts exist some matching mechanisms between poor defendants and attorneys. USA's courts utilize two kinds of mechanisms. First, the court selects an attorney for the defendant. In this case, participated attorneys in the market matches randomly to poor defendants. The second is the voucher mechanism, in which courts devote specific budgets to every indigent defendant, so he employs his attorney. According to \cite{r1}, this mechanism leads to positive assortative matching on cases difficulty and attorneys quality.

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

In courts exist some matching mechanisms between poor defendants and attorneys. USA’s
courts utilize two kinds of mechanisms. First, the court selects an attorney for the defendant. In
this case, participated attorneys in the market matches randomly to poor defendants. The second
is the voucher mechanism, in which courts devote specific budgets to every indigent defendant, so
he employs his attorney. According to r1, this mechanism leads to positive assortative matching
on cases difficulty and attorneys quality.

Comment: Have you run `biber`? See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162).  Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is there an entry with key `r1` in the file `sample.bib`? Incidentally, for better code robustness, you may want to replace `\bibliography{sample}` with `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`.

Comment: A suggestion: For the sake of code simplicity in what's meant to be a test or diagnostic document, you could replace the long paragraph that starts with "In courts" and ends with "and attorneys quality." with just "According to \cite{r1} ...".

Comment: Off topic: several packages are loaded more than once.  If options are specified for such packages, any options requested after the first loading will be ignored.  Also, with very few exceptions, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: Any news here? The most likely explanation of the undesirable output you see is indeed that Biber was not run. Most people who use an editor to compile stuff need to configure the editor accordingly (see the already linked https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). But it is also possible that your editor already runs Biber for your and the problem lies elsewhere. In that case you need to share more info with us (we need to see the `.blg` and `.log` files). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864 for starters. ...

Comment: ... In its current form and without any feedback from you, we cannot really answer this question properly. I am therefore going to vote to close it in due time if no updates are made.