# Convert .bib file for Overleaf in .bib file for TexStudio

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, overleaf

In my Overleaf document I created a .bib file with Overleaf-supported syntax (on Overleaf I always use `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}`), but when I copy my .bib file into TexStudio, this editor doesn't succed in read that .bib file.
I found motivation: Overleaf syntax is bitty different with respect TexStudio one.

Is possible to convert a .bib file for Overleaf in .bib file for TexStudio?
OR, does exist another way to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

**First Edit:** I use `pdfLatex distribution` and I setted `Biber` as indicated to myself in your comments. My problems are: `citation undefined`, why?

If it can be of use to you, the code of my .bib file (named `Frobenius.bib`)

```
@book{geodiff,
  author = {Graziano Gentili and Fabio Podestà and Edoardo Vesentini},
  year = {1995},
  title = {Lezioni di Geometria Differenziale},
  publisher = {Bollati Boringhieri},
  address = {Torino},
  edition = {1},
  pages = {3-6,11,13,22,29,31-33,42-45},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{lee,
  author = {John Marshall Lee},
  year = {2018},
  title = {Introduction to Smooth Manifolds},
  publisher = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics 218, Springer Verlag},
  address = {New York},
  edition = {2},
  pages = {490-514},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{wikien,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  year = {15 Maggio 2023},
  title = {Frobenius theorem (differential topology)},
  publisher = {Internet},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{wikifr,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  year = {23 Agosto 2022},
  title = {Théorème de Frobenius (géométrie différentielle)},
  publisher = {Internet},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)

@misc{wikien2,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  year = {2 Settembre 2023},
  title = {Sheaf (mathematics)},
  publisher = {Internet},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{mechanics,
  author = {Ralph Abraham and Jerrold Eldon Marsden},
  year = {2008},
  title = {Foundations of Mechanics},
  publisher = {Addison-- Wesley Publishing Company, lnc.},
  address = {California},
  edition = {2},
  pages = {93-95},
  keyword = {Meccanica}
}

@book{malusa,
  author = {Annalisa Malusa},
  year = {Agosto 2022},
  title = {Introduzione alle Equazioni Differenziali Oridinarie},
  publisher = {Indipendently published},
  address = {Torrazza Piemonte (TO)},
  edition = {2},
  pages = {47-67},
  keyword = {Analisi}
}

@article{Frobenius,
  author = {George Ferdinand Frobenius},
  journal = {Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik},
  pages = {230-315},
  title = {Ueber das Pfaffsche Problem.},
  url = {http://eudml.org/doc/148315},
  volume = {82},
  year = {1877},
  kewword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{han,
  author = {Chong--Kyu Han},
  year = {Maggio 2023},
  title = {Generalization of the Frobenius Theorem on involutivity},
  url = {http://www.math.snu.ac.kr/~ckhan/paperpdf/generalfrobenius.pdf},
  publisher = {Internet},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{robbinsalomon,
  author = {Joel William Robbin and Dietmar Arno Salamon},
  %year = {Maggio 2023},
  title = {Introduction to Differential Geometry},
  year = {11 Ottobre 2022},
  publisher = {Internet},
  url = {https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf},
  %publisher = {Internet},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{clebsch,
  author = {Rudolf Friedrich Alfred Clebsch},
  title  = {{Ueber die simultane Integration linearer partieller Differentialgleichungen.}},
  month = Gennaio,
  year  = {1 Gennaio 1866},
  publisher = {Zenodo},
  %pages = {230-315},
  doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  kewword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{deahna,
  author = {Heinrich Wilhelm Feodor Deahna},
  title  = {{Ueber die Bedingungen der Integrabilität lineärer Differentialgleichungen erster Ordnung zwischen einer beliebigen Anzahl veränderlicher Größen.}},
  year  = {1 Gennaio 1840},
  publisher = {Zenodo},
  %pages = {230-315},
  doi = {10.1515/crll.1840.20.340},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1840.20.340}
}

@article{whitney36,
  author = {Hassler Whitney},
  title = {Differentiable manifolds},
  month = Febbraio,
  year  = {10 Febbraio 1936},
  publisher = {JSTOR},
  pages = {230-315},
  doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url = {https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/courses/6701/whitney36.pdf},
  kewword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{osborn,
  author = {Howard Osborn},
  title = {Vector Bundles, Vol. 1, Foundations and Stielel--Whitney Classes},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
  year = 1982,
  pages = {28, 29, 50-52, 260, 291 294},
  url = {https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/osborn.pdf},
  keyword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{milnorS7,
  author = {John Wellard Milnor},
  title = {On Manifolds Homeomorphic to the 7--Sphere},
  month = Giugno,
  year  = {14 Giugno 1956},
  publisher = {JSTOR},
  %pages = {230-315},
  %doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url = {https://people.math.osu.edu/burghelea.1/MaterialDiffTopology/Milnorsphere.pdf},
  kewword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{kervaire10,
  author = {Michel André Kervaire},
  title = {A Manifold which does not not admit any Differentiable Structure.},
  month = Dicembre,
  year  = {12 Dicembre 2011},
  publisher = {JSTOR},
  %pages = {230-315},
  %doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url = {https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/kervaire.pdf},
  kewword = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{penot,
  author = {Nicolas Hadjisavvas and Jean--Paul Penot},
  title = {Revisiting the problem of integrability in utility theory},
  pages = {1-15},
  month = Settembre,
  year  = {01 Settembre 2015},
  volume = {64},
  journal = {Optimization},
  doi = {10.1080/02331934.2015.1080701},
  kewword = {Economia}
}

@article{samuelson,
  ISSN = {00130427, 14680335},
  URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2549499},
  author = {Paul Anthony Samuelson},
  journal = {Economica},
  number = {68},
  pages = {355--385},
  publisher = {[London School of Economics, Wiley, London School of Economics and Political Science, Suntory and Toyota International Centres for Economics and Related Disciplines]},
  title = {The Problem of Integrability in Utility Theory},
  urldate = {2024-02-26},
  volume = {17},
  year = {1950},
  kewword = {Economia}
}

@article{samuelson2,
 ISSN = {00130427, 14680335},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2549561},
 author = {Paul Anthony Samuelson},
 journal = {Economica},
 number = {60},
 pages = {243--253},
 publisher = {[London School of Economics, Wiley, London School of Economics and Political Science, Suntory and Toyota International Centres for Economics and Related Disciplines]},
 title = {Consumption Theory in Terms of Revealed Preference},
 urldate = {2024-02-27},
 volume = {15},
 year = {1948}
}

@book{dieudonné,
  title={Foundations of Modern Analysis},
  author={Jean Dieudonne},
  isbn={9781446547519},
  url={https://books.google.it/books?id=gU58CgAAQBAJ},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Read Books Limited}
}
```

Comment: There should not be any difference between Overleaf and TexStudio, the syntax of bib files is exactly the same. What do you mean exactly with "TexStudio doesn't succed in read[ing] that .bib file"? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say? Is the problem while loading the file or while compiling your document? Did you select Biber as a bibliography compiler in TexStudio instead of BibTeX?

Comment: The `.bib` syntax is always the same no matter which editor you use. There are subtle differences between the meanings of fields etc. when you change between `biblatex` or BibTeX (or indeed between different BIbTeX/`biblatex` styles), but that should usually not lead to errors. It's more likely that your local setup with TeXstudio is not exactly the same as Overleaf. Overleaf runs `latexmk` which can run Biber etc. for you automatically. Locally you may have to configure your editor to run Biber for you https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: TeXstudio is an editor and a front-end to a (back-end) TeX distribution. (Overleaf uses TeXLive as its back-end.) Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you most recently update your TeX distribution?

Comment: What's with the line `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)`? Should it be deleted?

Comment: Thx for your comments, I edited my question; Please read **First Edit:**. I deleted **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)**-line

Comment: If you did run Biber, you should find a `.blg` file (despite what your computer may tell you this is a simple text file you can open with any text editor), what does it say? Copy the complete contents into your question.

Comment: You'll also want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864.

Comment: overleaf and texstudio do not process the bib file at all they are just the editors you can use to write it the syntax is that of biber so is the same in both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your bib file contains numerous inconsistencies and errors. One of them is the use of the `@article` entry type for entries that do not appear to have been published in scholarly journals; I suggest you use the catch-all `@misc` entry type for these -- unless, of course, you can come up with better alternatives. Quite a few of your entries fail to make effective use of the `date` field, which is new to biblatex/biber and isn't recognized by BibTeX.

The field

```
publisher= {Graduate Texts in Mathematics 218, Springer Verlag},
```

combines information that should be spread over three fields:

```
series   = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
number   = {218},
publisher= {Springer Verlag},
```

You also ask,

> My problems are: citation undefined, why?

Since your posting doesn't contain any `\cite` instructions, this question simply cannot be answered with the information you've chosen to provide.

The following screenshot shows the first few entries of the updated bib file. It was compiled with TeXworks as the front end and MacTeX2023 as the back end. As long as your TeX distribution is set up correctly and is reasonably up to date, you should have no problems recreating it with TeXstudio.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

%% create a bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{geodiff,
  author   = {Graziano Gentili and Fabio Podestà and Edoardo Vesentini},
  year     = {1995},
  title    = {Lezioni di Geometria Differenziale},
  publisher= {Bollati Boringhieri},
  address  = {Torino},
  edition  = {1},
  pages    = {3-6,11,13,22,29,31-33,42-45},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{lee,
  author   = {John Marshall Lee},
  year     = {2018},
  title    = {Introduction to Smooth Manifolds},
  series   = {Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
  number   = 218,
  publisher= {Springer Verlag},
  address  = {New York},
  edition  = {2},
  pages    = {490-514},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{wikien,
  author   = {Wikipedia},
  date     = {2023-05-15},
  title    = {Frobenius theorem (differential topology)},
  publisher= {Internet},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{wikifr,
  author   = {Wikipedia},
  date     = {2022-08-23},
  title    = {Théorème de Frobenius (géométrie différentielle)},
  publisher= {Internet},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

%https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)

@misc{wikien2,
  author   = {Wikipedia},
  date     = {2023-09-02},
  title    = {Sheaf (mathematics)},
  publisher= {Internet},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{mechanics,
  author   = {Ralph Abraham and Jerrold Eldon Marsden},
  year     = {2008},
  title    = {Foundations of Mechanics},
  publisher= {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, lnc.},
  address  = {California},
  edition  = {2},
  pages    = {93-95},
  keyword  = {Meccanica}
}

@book{malusa,
  author   = {Annalisa Malusa},
  month    = aug,
  year     = {2022},
  title    = {Introduzione alle Equazioni Differenziali Oridinarie},
  publisher= {Indipendently published},
  address  = {Torrazza Piemonte (TO)},
  edition  = {2},
  pages    = {47-67},
  keyword  = {Analisi}
}

@article{Frobenius,
  author   = {George Ferdinand Frobenius},
  journal  = {Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik},
  pages    = {230-315},
  title    = {Über das Pfaffsche Problem},
  url      = {http://eudml.org/doc/148315},
  volume   = {82},
  year     = {1877},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{han,
  author   = {Chong-Kyu Han},
  month    = may,
  year     = {2023},
  title    = {Generalization of the Frobenius Theorem on involutivity},
  url      = {http://www.math.snu.ac.kr/~ckhan/paperpdf/generalfrobenius.pdf},
  publisher= {Internet},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{robbinsalomon,
  author   = {Joel William Robbin and Dietmar Arno Salamon},
  %year = {Maggio 2023},
  title    = {Introduction to Differential Geometry},
  date     = {2022-10-11},
  publisher= {Internet},
  url      = {https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf},
  %publisher = {Internet},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{clebsch,
  author   = {Rudolf Friedrich Alfred Clebsch},
  title    = {{Über die simultane Integration linearer partieller Differentialgleichungen.}},
  xmonth   = {Gennaio},
  date     = {1866-01-01},
  publisher= {Zenodo},
  %pages = {230-315},
  doi      = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url      = {https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{deahna,
  author   = {Heinrich Wilhelm Feodor Deahna},
  title    = {{Über die Bedingungen der Integrabilität linearer 
             Differentialgleichungen erster Ordnung zwischen einer 
             beliebigen Anzahl veränderlicher Größen}},
  date     = {1840-01-01},
  publisher= {Zenodo},
  %pages = {230-315},
  doi      = {10.1515/crll.1840.20.340},
  url      = {https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1840.20.340}
}

@misc{whitney36,
  author   = {Hassler Whitney},
  title    = {Differentiable manifolds},
  xmonth   = {Febbraio},
  date     = {1936-02-10},
  publisher= {JSTOR},
  pages    = {230--315},
  doi      = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url      = {https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/courses/6701/whitney36.pdf},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@book{osborn,
  author   = {Howard Osborn},
  title    = {Vector Bundles, Vol. 1, Foundations and Stielel-Whitney Classes},
  publisher= {Academic Press},
  year     = 1982,
  pages    = {28, 29, 50--52, 260, 291--294},
  url      = {https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/osborn.pdf},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@isc{milnorS7,
  author   = {John Wellard Milnor},
  title    = {On Manifolds Homeomorphic to the 7-Sphere},
  xmonth   = {Giugno},
  date     = {1956-06-14},
  publisher= {JSTOR},
  %pages = {230-315},
  %doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url      = {https://people.math.osu.edu/burghelea.1/MaterialDiffTopology/Milnorsphere.pdf},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@misc{kervaire10,
  author   = {Michel André Kervaire},
  title    = {A Manifold which does not admit any Differentiable Structure},
  xmonth   = {Dicembre},
  date     = {2011-12-12},
  publisher= {JSTOR},
  %pages = {230-315},
  %doi = {10.1515/crll.1866.65.257},
  url      = {https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/kervaire.pdf},
  keyword  = {Geometria Differenziale}
}

@article{penot,
  author   = {Nicolas Hadjisavvas and Jean-Paul Penot},
  title    = {Revisiting the problem of integrability in utility theory},
  pages    = {1-15},
  xmonth   = {Settembre},
  date     = {2015-09-01},
  volume   = {64},
  journal  = {Optimization},
  doi      = {10.1080/02331934.2015.1080701},
  keyword  = {Economia}
}

@article{samuelson,
  ISSN     = {00130427, 14680335},
  URL      = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2549499},
  author   = {Paul Anthony Samuelson},
  journal  = {Economica},
  number   = {68},
  pages    = {355--385},
  publisher= {[London School of Economics, Wiley, London School of Economics 
               and Political Science, Suntory and Toyota International Centres 
               for Economics and Related Disciplines]},
  title    = {The Problem of Integrability in Utility Theory},
  urldate  = {2024-02-26},
  volume   = {17},
  year     = {1950},
  keyword  = {Economia}
}

@article{samuelson2,
 ISSN      = {00130427, 14680335},
 URL       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2549561},
 author    = {Paul Anthony Samuelson},
 journal   = {Economica},
 number    = {60},
 pages     = {243--253},
 publisher = {[London School of Economics, Wiley, London School of Economics 
               and Political Science, Suntory and Toyota International Centres 
               for Economics and Related Disciplines]},
 title     = {Consumption Theory in Terms of Revealed Preference},
 urldate   = {2024-02-27},
 volume    = {15},
 year      = {1948}
}

@book{dieudonne,
  title    = {Foundations of Modern Analysis},
  author   = {Jean Dieudonné},
  isbn     = {9781446547519},
  url      = {https://books.google.it/books?id=gU58CgAAQBAJ},
  year     = {2011},
  publisher= {Read Books Ltd.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL strings

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know what it is happened, but (wonderfully) my bibliography functions very well, as in Overleaf, and regardless of Mico's response!

Comment: @Puck - Do please make an effort to fix the weaknesses in the bib file.